# Use of integer instead of interval (of one type)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, datatypes, database-tuning, storage

Our DB design presently has a `interval` column which will only be storing days (no other interval type) so it is making sense to use `INT2` (`smallint`) instead of `interval`. [Reference to documentation.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html)

Advantage: 2 bytes instead of 12 bytes (we have many such columns).

Is this line of thinking ok or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Sounds OK to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perfectly ok - especially since you can add and subtract `integer` to / from `date` directly in Postgres.

However, `smallint` (`int2`) might not be better than a plain **`integer`** (`int4`). True, `integer` occupies 4 bytes instead of 2, but many operations are optimized for `integer`. Among other things, `integer` is the default numeric type for (sufficiently small) numbers without decimal point. For `int2` you often need to add an explicit cast.

Also, you probably gain *nothing* for a single column in regard to storage or RAM. Some closer understanding of storage mechanisms is needed here, in particular *alignment padding*.

For several `int2` columns in a table  (or even "many" as you mention) and know what you are doing, the odds for `int2` get better.

See:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)
- [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/939860)

If in doubt, run a test and measure:

- [Measure the size of a PostgreSQL table row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/measure-the-size-of-a-postgresql-table-row/23933#23933)

Comment: Plus I always think that modern 64bit processors can't handle a two-byte integer anyway. I might be mistaken, but I don't think they can physically handle less than 64bit, everything else is just setting all the other bits to zero (but I could be mistaken there)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163254/on-32-bit-cpus-is-an-integer-type-more-efficient-than-a-short-type what I understood is performance penalty, if any, is negligible as compared to memory storing and cache hits. But, a good point which should be considered. in fact int8 will be better for 64bit but I am more focused on diskIO.

Comment: @Erwin Brandsetter I do have several columns in a table and many such tables :). Some of the table do have 8 columns (or more) of INT2. Casting of INT2 is definitely I will keep in mind.

Comment: @vedic: I didn't really think that an int2 will be slower than an int8 on processor level. My point was that it won't be a difference once the data is in memory.