# Improve performance of COUNT/GROUP-BY in large PostgresSQL table?

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, group-by, count

I am running PostgresSQL 9.2 and have a 12 column relation with about 6,700,000 rows. It contains nodes in a 3D space, each one referencing a user (who created it). To query which user has created how many nodes I do the following (added `explain analyze` for more information):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT user_id, count(user_id) FROM treenode WHERE project_id=1 GROUP BY user_id;
                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=253668.70..253669.07 rows=37 width=8) (actual time=1747.620..1747.623 rows=38 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on treenode  (cost=0.00..220278.79 rows=6677983 width=8) (actual time=0.019..886.803 rows=6677983 loops=1)
         Filter: (project_id = 1)
 Total runtime: 1747.653 ms
```

As you can see, this takes about 1.7 seconds. This isn't too bad considering the amount of data, but I wonder if this can be improved. I tried to add a BTree index on the user column, but this didn't help in any way.

Do you have alternative suggestions?

---

For the sake of completeness, this is the complete table definition with all it's indices (without foreign key constraints, references and triggers):

```
    Column     |           Type           |                      Modifiers                    
---------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
 id            | bigint                   | not null default nextval('concept_id_seq'::regclass)
 user_id       | bigint                   | not null
 creation_time | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()
 edition_time  | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()
 project_id    | bigint                   | not null
 location      | double3d                 | not null
 reviewer_id   | integer                  | not null default (-1)
 review_time   | timestamp with time zone |
 editor_id     | integer                  |
 parent_id     | bigint                   |
 radius        | double precision         | not null default 0
 confidence    | integer                  | not null default 5
 skeleton_id   | bigint                   |
Indexes:
    "treenode_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "treenode_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (id)
    "skeleton_id_treenode_index" btree (skeleton_id)
    "treenode_editor_index" btree (editor_id)
    "treenode_location_x_index" btree (((location).x))
    "treenode_location_y_index" btree (((location).y))
    "treenode_location_z_index" btree (((location).z))
    "treenode_parent_id" btree (parent_id)
    "treenode_user_index" btree (user_id)
```

---

**Edit:** This is the result, when I use the query (and index) proposed by @ypercube (query takes about 5.3 seconds without `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT u.id, ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM treenode AS t WHERE t.project_id=1 AND t.user_id = u.id ) AS number_of_nodes FROM auth_user As u;
                                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                                     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on auth_user u  (cost=0.00..6987937.85 rows=46 width=4) (actual time=29.934..5556.147 rows=46 loops=1)
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Aggregate  (cost=151911.65..151911.66 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=120.780..120.780 rows=1 loops=46)
           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on treenode t  (cost=4634.41..151460.44 rows=180486 width=0) (actual time=13.785..114.021 rows=145174 loops=46)
                 Recheck Cond: ((project_id = 1) AND (user_id = u.id))
                 Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 461076
                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on treenode_user_index  (cost=0.00..4589.29 rows=180486 width=0) (actual time=13.082..13.082 rows=145174 loops=46)
                       Index Cond: ((project_id = 1) AND (user_id = u.id))
 Total runtime: 5556.190 ms
(9 rows)

Time: 5556.804 ms
```

---

**Edit 2:** This is the result, when I use an `index` on `project_id, user_id` (but no schema optimization, yet) as @erwin-brandstetter suggested (the query runs with 1.5 seconds at the same speed as my original query):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT user_id, count(user_id) as ct FROM treenode WHERE project_id=1 GROUP BY user_id;
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=253670.88..253671.24 rows=37 width=8) (actual time=1807.334..1807.339 rows=38 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on treenode  (cost=0.00..220280.62 rows=6678050 width=8) (actual time=0.183..893.491 rows=6678050 loops=1)
         Filter: (project_id = 1)
 Total runtime: 1807.368 ms
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Do you also have a table `Users` with `user_id` as the primary key?

Comment: I just saw that there's a third party columnstore addon for Postgres. Also, I just wanted to post from the new ios app

Comment: Thanks for the good, clear, complete question - versions, table definitions, etc.

Comment: @ypercube Yes, I've got a Users table.

Comment: How many different `project_id` and `user_id`? Is the table updated continuously or could you work with a materialized view (for some time)?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: There are usually not more than five different `project_id` and 50 `user_id` entries. This table is updated continuously.

Comment: That should have been in your question to begin with ... Added a chapter to my answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Main problem is the missing index. But there is more.

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) AS ct
FROM   treenode
WHERE  project_id = 1
GROUP  BY user_id;
```

- You have many `bigint` columns. Probably overkill. Typically, [`integer`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) is more than enough for columns like `project_id` and `user_id`. This would also help the next item.
  While optimizing the table definition, consider this related answer, with an emphasis on *data alignment* and *padding*. Most of the rest applies, too:

  - [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)
- The **elephant in the room**: there is no **index on `project_id`**. Create one. This is more important than the rest of this answer.
  While being at it, make that a multicolumn index:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX treenode_project_id_user_id_index ON treenode (project_id, user_id);
  ```

  If you followed my advice, `integer` would be perfect here. See:

  - [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)
- `user_id` is defined `NOT NULL`, so `count(user_id)` is equivalent to `count(*)`, but the latter is a bit shorter and faster. (For the given query, this even applies without `user_id` being defined `NOT NULL`.)
- `id` is already the primary key, the additional `UNIQUE` constraint is **useless ballast**. Drop it:

  ```
  "treenode_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)  
  "treenode_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (id)
  ```

#### Added information

Q: *"How many different project_id and user_id?"*
A: *"Not more than five different project_id."*

That means Postgres has to read **about 20% of the whole table** to satisfy your query. Unless it can use an **index-only scan**, a sequential scan on the table will be faster than involving any indexes. No more performance to gain here - except by optimizing the table and server settings.

As for the **index-only scan**: To see how effective that can be, run `VACUUM ANALYZE`. Then try your query again. It should now be moderately faster using *only* the index. Read this related answer first:

- [Optimize simple query using ORDER BY date and text](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48630/optimize-simple-query-using-order-by-date-and-text/48633#48633)

As well as:

- [The manual on index-only scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html)
- [Postgres Wiki on index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans).

Comment: Erwin, thanks for your suggestions. You are right, for `user_id` and `project_id` `integer` should be more than enough. Using `count(*)` instead of `count(user_id)` saves about 70ms here, that's good to know. I've added the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of the query after I've added your suggested `index` to the first post. It doesn't improve the performance, though (but also doesn't hurt). It seems the `index` isn't used at all. I will test the schema optimizations soon.

Comment: If I disable `seqscan`, the index is used (`Index Only Scan using treenode_project_id_user_id_index on treenode`), but the query takes about 2.5 seconds then (which is about 1 second longer than with seqscan).

Comment: Thanks for your update. These missing bits should have been part of my question, that is right. I just wasn't aware of their impact. I'll optimize my schema like you suggested---let's see what I can gain from that. Thanks for your explanation, it makes sense to me and therefore I'll mark your answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 9):

I'd first add an index on `(project_id, user_id)` and then in 9.3 version, try this query:

```
SELECT u.user_id, c.number_of_nodes 
FROM users AS u
   , LATERAL
     ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS number_of_nodes 
       FROM treenode AS t
       WHERE t.project_id = 1 
         AND t.user_id = u.user_id
     ) c 
-- WHERE c.number_of_nodes > 0 ;   -- you probably want this as well
                                   -- to show only relevant users
```

In 9.2, try this one:

```
SELECT u.user_id, 
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM treenode AS t
         WHERE t.project_id = 1 
           AND t.user_id = u.user_id
       ) AS number_of_nodes  
FROM users AS u ;
```

I assume you have a `users` table. If not, replace `users` with:
`(SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM treenode)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You are correct, I've got a users table. However, using your query in 9.2 it takes about 5 seconds to get the result--regardless whether the index is created or not. I created the index like this: `CREATE INDEX treenode_user_index ON treenode USING btree (project_id, user_id);`, but I tried also without the `USING` clause. Do I miss something?

Comment: How many row are there in the `users` table and how many rows does the query return (so how many users are there that have `project_id=1`)? Can you show the explain of this query, after you added the index?

Comment: First, I was wrong in my first comment. Without your suggested index it takes about 40s (!) to retrieve the result. It takes about 5s with the `index` in place. Sorry for the confusion. In my `users` table I've got 46 entries. The query returns only 9 rows. Surprisingly, `SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM treenode WHERE project_id=1;` returns 38 rows. I've added the `explain` to my first post. And to prevent confusion: my `users` table is actually called `auth_user`.

Comment: I wonder how can `SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM treenode WHERE project_id=1;` returns 38 rows while the queries return only 9. Buffled.

Comment: Can you try this?: `SET enable_seqscan = OFF; (Query); SET enable_seqscan = ON;`

Comment: I just found out: The query _does_ actually return 46 rows as expected, but only 38 have a different `number_of_nodes` value than `0`. I am really sorry, I just confused the output from the `explain` (`(9 rows)`) with the actual result. I've also tried setting `seqscan` on and off. It doesn't make a difference.

Comment: OK, right. I could add another layer to remove those rows where the count is 0, I just didn't want to complicate the query so the logic is obvious. And how much time does your query take (with the index in place)?

Comment: Your query, with index in place, takes about 5.3 seconds. The `group-by/count` query I started with takes about 1.5 seconds.

Comment: Then keep your query :) I think I'll have to delete  this answer.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for trying to help. At least I learned that the number of rows returned by `explain` don't reflect the actual query and that your suggested way isn't faster. :-)

Comment: Check this question and the discussion as well: [PostgreSQL query runs faster with index scan, but engine chooses hash join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643215/postgresql-query-runs-faster-with-index-scan-but-engine-chooses-hash-join). Not really sure if this 100% relevant, wait for someone with more knowledge on Postgres' optimizer to answer your question.