# Postgres: check disk space taken by materialized view?

Tags: postgresql, disk-space, materialized-view, database-size

I know how to check the size of indexes and tables in Postgres (I'm using version 9.4):

```
SELECT
   relname AS objectname,
   relkind AS objecttype,
   reltuples AS "#entries", pg_size_pretty(relpages::bigint*8*1024) AS size
   FROM pg_class
   WHERE relpages >= 8
   ORDER BY relpages DESC;
```

But this doesn't show materialized views. How can I check how much disk space they are taking up?

Answer (score 29):

This is assuming that materialized views have `relpages >= 8` in `pg_class`, which doesn't have to be the case. It can actually be empty - not populated yet, indicated by `pg_class.relispopulated = FALSE`. The corresponding disk file has a *zero* size in this case.

Try instead:

```
SELECT oid::regclass::text  AS objectname
     , relkind   AS objecttype
     , reltuples AS entries
     , pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size(oid)) AS size  -- depending - see below
FROM   pg_class
WHERE  relkind IN ('r', 'i', 'm')
ORDER  BY pg_table_size(oid) DESC;
```

The cast to `regclass` makes sure that the name of the relation is quoted and schema-qualified where needed (where the current `search_path` would not resolve to the same object). See:

- [Missing "public" schema when converting a "regclass" value to text](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207911/missing-public-schema-when-converting-a-regclass-value-to-text/207917#207917)

[Available values for `relkind` are](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html):

> `r` = ordinary table,
> `i` = index,
> `S` = sequence,
> `v` = view,
> `m` = materialized view,
> `c` = composite type,
> `t` = TOAST table,
> `f` = foreign table

Use one of the [database object size functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE) rather than building your own. Be aware that the "size of a table" can be defined in different ways. Details:

- [Measure the size of a PostgreSQL table row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/measure-the-size-of-a-postgresql-table-row/23933#23933)

Comment: Correct answer indeed. Note that order by size is misleading as you're printing size in human-readable form making ordering sort lexicographically

Comment: @Jack: Good point. I added a more sensible `ORDER BY`.