# Missing "public" schema when converting a "regclass" value to text

Tags: postgresql, catalogs, string-representation, regclass

I am writing a script in which I need to parse the name of a table (in `regclass`). The parsing (with `parse_ident()`) works so far. However, the script fails when the table is in the `public` schema because PostgreSQL (10.3) automatically removes the schema name.

For example, if a table `tt` is in a non-`public` schema `ex`, the text value of the `regclass` is the same as the original:

```
=> select 'ex.tt'::regclass::text;
 text  
-------
 ex.tt
```

When it's in `public`, the schema name is lost:

```
=> select 'public.tt'::regclass::text;
 text 
------
 tt
```

Is there an way to disable this behavior, or to convert to `text` without losing the schema name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not related to the schema `public` per se - which is just another schema with no special powers except that it's created by default - and included in the `search_path` by default.

The current **`search_path`** is behind this. The text representation of a [`regclass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) value builds on it. The table name is only schema-qualified if the schema is not the first match in the `search_path` anyway. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html):

> The `regclass` input converter handles the table lookup according to the
> schema path setting, and so it does the “right thing” automatically.
> Similarly, casting a table's OID to `regclass` is handy for symbolic
> display of a numeric OID.

You could force Postgres to print the schema name by setting an empty `search_path` (locally):

```
SET LOCAL search_path = '';
SELECT 'public.tt'::regclass::text;
```

But that forces you to schema-qualify everything for the rest of the transaction or until you set the `search_path` again. Well, *most* everything, `pg_catalog` and `pg_temp` are special. See:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860)

Or you avoid the special cast and the `search_path` and get the schema name from `pg_class` directly:

```
SELECT relnamespace::regnamespace::text
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class
WHERE  oid = 'public.tt'::regclass;
```