# PostgreSQL window functions very slow on big table

Tags: postgresql, performance, window-functions, query-performance

I have a PostgreSQL table constructed as

```
device_id | point     | dt_edit
----------+-----------+----------
100       | geometry  | timestamp
101       | geometry  | timestamp
100       | geometry  | timestamp
102       | geometry  | timestamp
102       | geometry  | timestamp
101       | geometry  | timestamp
```

I need to select the last 2 records ordered by `dt_edit` from unique `device_id`. This query works very slow, on 1 billion records - 500 seconds:

```
 SELECT dt.device_id,
    dt.point,
    dt.dt_edit
   FROM ( SELECT gps_data.device_id,
            gps_data.point,
            gps_data.dt_edit,
            rank() OVER (PARTITION BY gps_data.device_id
                         ORDER BY gps_data.dt_edit DESC) AS rank
           FROM gps_data) dt
  WHERE dt.rank <= 2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show \d gps_data? I'm looking for indexes on the table.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: I assume 1 billion is the number of rows in the table, not the size of the result. What is the cardinality of device_id, i.e. how many unique device_id are there?

Comment: can you send an "explain analyze select ..." ... it would be nice to see

Comment: Can we assume that a `device` table holding all devices exists? Also, where you use `rank()`, do you actually mean rank() or rather `row_number()` - the latter would return no more then two rows per device. Please provide a table definition and your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we can assume a `device` table holding all devices of interest. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE device (device_id int, device text);
INSERT INTO device (device_id, device) VALUES
  (100, 'a')
, (101, 'b')
, (102, 'c');
```

The query can be very simple:

```
SELECT d.device_id, g.point, g.dt_edit
FROM   device d
,      LATERAL (
   SELECT point, dt_edit
   FROM   gps_data
   WHERE  device_id = d.device_id
   ORDER  BY dt_edit DESC NULLS LAST -- more items?
   LIMIT  2
   ) g;
```

Assuming a much smaller cardinality in table `device` than in table `gps_data`, i.e. ***many*** rows per device in the latter.

If `dt_edit` is not `UNIQUE`, add more items to `ORDER BY` to disambiguate the sort order.

All you need for this to be ***fast*** is a multicolumn index;

```
CREATE INDEX gps_data_foo_idx
ON gps_data (device_id, dt_edit DESC NULLS LAST); -- more items?
```

The `NULLS LAST` modifier is useful if the column can be NULL, but does not hurt in any case. Either way, the query must match the index.

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511492/939860)

If you don't have a device table, I would suggest to create one (and keep it current).
But there are ways to make this fast even without `device` table ...

Details:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)
- [How do I efficiently get "the most recent corresponding row"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/how-do-i-efficiently-get-the-most-recent-corresponding-row/49555#49555)
- [SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/102677/3684)