# Aggregate rows of type array

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, array

I need to aggregate rows with a single column of type `INT[]` into a single array of type `INT[]`.

The following results in an error "could not find array type for data type integer[]":

```
create temp table vals (j int[])
on commit drop;
insert into vals
values ('{1,2}'), ('{1,5}'), ('{3,6}');
select array_agg(j) from vals;
```

The result that I need from the example is a single row that looks like `{1,2,1,5,3,6}`

The order of records is unimportant as long as the paired numbers remain adjacent to each other in the final array.

I'm out of ideas. How can I get the result that I need?

(PostgreSQL 9.4, Ubuntu 15.04)

Comment: What defines the order of rows in vals? You must define it, there is no natural order. Maybe just `ORDER BY i, j`? Also, please clarify: you mention `rows with a single column of type INT[]`, but demonstrate a table with two plain `int` columns. Which is it?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter The temp table is just for illustration purposes. In reality, my input table is a single column of type INT[]. The example accomplishes this by wrapping i and j in an ARRAY call. I've updated the question to make this more clear.

Comment: The updated question is a simpler variant. Consider the added solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Order of source rows irrelevant, source is array column

Your updated requirements are much simpler for two reasons:

- We don't need to establish any order among source rows.
- And the array already establishes order among array elements.

Simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE vals (j int[]);
```

Simple query:

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT elem FROM vals, unnest(j) elem) AS arr;
```

#### Order of source rows relevant, source are integer columns

Not as simple. Based on this table:

```
CREATE TABLE vals (i int, j int);
```

There are various ways to preserve order. I think this should be among the fastest - with an [ARRAY constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS):

```
SELECT ARRAY(
   SELECT t.elem
   FROM  (SELECT i, j FROM vals ORDER BY i, j) v
        , LATERAL (VALUES (v.i), (v.j)) t(elem)
   ) AS arr;
```

My first draft had `ORDER BY i, j` after the `LATERAL` join, which would not guarantee the order of columns. I pulled the `ORDER BY` into a subselect to produce the correct order now. This works, but it's not documented. To be absolutely sure, you have to add an explicit `ORDER BY` later:

```
SELECT ARRAY (
   SELECT elem
   FROM   vals v, LATERAL (VALUES (1, v.i), (2, v.j)) t(ordr, elem)
   ORDER  BY v.i, v.j, ordr
   ) AS arr;
```

About guaranteed order:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8767450/939860)

About the `VALUES` expression in a `LATERAL` join:

- [SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102677/select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/102743#102743)

Another way with - this time with [`array_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE):

```
SELECT array_agg(elem) AS arr
FROM  (
   SELECT i, j, 1 AS ordr, i AS elem FROM vals
   UNION ALL
   SELECT i, j, 2 AS ordr, j AS elem FROM vals
   ORDER BY i, j, ordr
   ) sub;
```

The ARRAY constructor is faster, `array_agg()` is easier to integrate with multiple result columns.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/78060/1)

---

The query in your test case would actually work in Postgres 9.5 (currently beta, to be released in the course of 2015). Quoting the [release notes for pg 9.5](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/release-9-5.html#AEN126073):

> Allow `array_agg()` and `ARRAY()` to take arrays as inputs (Ali Akbar, Tom
>   Lane)

**However**, you get a 2-dimenstional array instead, not your desired result.  You can easily implement the same (but slower) aggregate function in older versions:

- [Is there something like a zip() function in PostgreSQL that combines two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12414884/939860)

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL 9.5+, one could use `select string_to_array(string_agg(array_to_string(array_column_here, ','), ','), ',') from xxx` to aggregate arrays into 1-dimension array

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own aggregation function:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_flat (anyarray)
(
    sfunc = array_cat,
    stype = anyarray,
    initcond = '{}'
);
```

So now it will do exactly what you want:

```
select array_agg_flat(j) from vals;

RESULT:
{1,2,1,5,3,6}
```