# How do I convert a single column into multiple rows entries in postgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have a table shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (sl_no int, username text, petname1 text, petname2 text);
    
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  (1, 'A', 'XYZ', 'ABC')
, (2, 'B', 'RTS', 'DEF')
, (3, 'C', 'QWE', 'GHI')
, (4, 'D', 'HGD', 'JKL')
;
```

How do I convert a single column to multiple row entries?
into this result:

```
1, 'A', 'XYZ'
1, 'A', 'ABC'
2, 'B', 'RTS'
2, 'B', 'DEF'
3, 'C', 'QWE'
3, 'C', 'GHI'
4, 'D', 'HGD'
4, 'D', 'JKL'
```

using postgresql 11.3 if possible

Comment: See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102702/3684

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
select * from (
select sl_no, username, petname1 from tbl
union all
select sl_no, username, petname2 from tbl
) t order by 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this **without** querying the table a second time, using an unpivot. The easiest way to do that is with `CROSS JOIN LATERAL (VALUES`

```sql
SELECT
  t.sl_no,
  t.username,
  v.petname
FROM tbl t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (VALUES
    (petname1),
    (petname2)
) v(petname);
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=cb741c82502e5d3adaa510dc62255a41)