# Transpose 1 row into columns with count/sum

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have a a single row with age buckets as column names. I want them all in one column with their count or sum whatever I end up doing. I have quite a few buckets but for the sake of this example I've kept it simple. Please see the attached picture of the data and the outcome that is needed.

[image]

Comment: Please provide data as ***text***. Best as usable test case. Never as image. And always your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`VALUES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-values.html) expression in a [`LATERAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) join is among the most elegant solutions:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM   tbl t
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   VALUES
     ('age5' , t.age5)
   , ('age10', t.age10)
   , ('age15', t.age15)
   , ('age20', t.age20)
   ) x (bucket_name, bucket_value);
```

See:

- [SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102677/select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/102702)