# Is it possible to set order in which inherited tables a scanned in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, performance, explain, inheritance, postgresql-performance

I have a postgresql `measurement` table which is partitioned based on `logdate` column by month. Suppose I have `city_id` integer column and want to select latest row with `city_id = 125`.

When I run `explain select * from measurement where city_id = 125 limit 1;` I get

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..3.39 rows=1 width=12)
  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..308.25 rows=91 width=12)
     ->  Seq Scan on measurement  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=12)
           Filter: (city_id = 125)
     ->  Seq Scan on measurement_y2006m01  (cost=0.00..34.25 rows=10 width=12)
           Filter: (city_id = 125)
     ->  Seq Scan on measurement_y2006m02  (cost=0.00..34.25 rows=10 width=12)
           Filter: (city_id = 125)
     ->  Seq Scan on measurement_y2006m03  (cost=0.00..34.25 rows=10 width=12)
           Filter: (city_id = 125)
```

What is the default order in which those `Seq Scan` actions are performed on inherited tables? And can I explicitly set it so that the latest tables are scanned first as I am expecting to select recently added rows more often?

Answer (score 1):

> I ...  want to select **latest** row with `city_id = 125`.

Bold emphasis mine. Your query does not match the declared objective. Should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM measurement WHERE city_id = 125 ORDER BY logdate DESC LIMIT  1;
```

Which should make Postgres scan the latest partition first.

Assuming `logdate` is defined `NOT NULL`. Else use `ORDER BY logdate DESC NULLS LAST`:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511492/939860)

If that doesn't work for some reason (your setup and Postgres version are undisclosed), you can also spell it out:

```
(SELECT * FROM  measurement_y2006m03 WHERE city_id = 125 ORDER BY logdate DESC)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM  measurement_y2006m02 WHERE city_id = 125 ORDER BY logdate DESC)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM  measurement_y2006m01 WHERE city_id = 125 ORDER BY logdate DESC)
LIMIT  1;
```

Parentheses are *required* to make the `ORDER BY` apply to each `SELECT` instead of the whole query. Maybe you get an even better query plan by adding `LIMIT 1` to each `SELECT` additionally. You'll have to test.

Postgres will stop scanning as soon as it has found the first row. Related answers with more explanation:

- [Way to try multiple SELECTs till a result is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14365613/939860)
- [Use column values in ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116043/use-column-values-in-order-by-and-limit-clauses/116099#116099)

#### Index

For best performance you would have composite indices on `(city_id, logdate DESC)` on all child tables (or at least the latest ones).

Comment: Thanks for answer!. I see. the "latest" part was misleading. Theese are example tables from postgres docs on inheritance. In my case The `city_id`would be `uuid` which presumably will be unique across all inherited tables and of course they will be indexed by that field. I just need to select first record by `uuit` in all tables, but to check recent tables first. Is it possible?

Comment: Postgresql version is 9.4

Comment: If your question is misleading, I suggest you fix your question first. All relevant information should be in the question - your table definition, too. Consider instructions in the tag info to `[postgresql-performance]` I added.