# Calculate storage size of rows?

Tags: postgresql

In a multi-tenant only one DB, one column is used to isolate customers data, that is customer_id.

Is it possible to get the storage size of a certain customer in all tables?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`pg_column_size()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE) to get the size of a complete row, not only for a single column.

So to find the size of all rows for a specific customer, you can use something like this:

```
select sum(pg_column_size(t) + 24) 
from the_table t
where customer_id = 42;
```

(The 24 is the storage overhead per row in a table)

You would need to do that for all tables you are interested in.

This does however not include the size of those rows in the indexes.

Comment: Do you mean that the size of indexes is not retrieved?

Comment: @simo: correct, that query does not include the size of indexed columns.

Comment: is there any workaround to get indexed columns too?

Comment: hands down the best way to do this [Erwin's way here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/measure-the-size-of-a-postgresql-table-row/23933)