# Database is 300 GB, but I only see small tables?

Tags: postgresql, psql, database-size

I wonder why my database is so large. I type:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('defaultdb'));
```

and it says defaultdb is 259 GB. That is huge.

So I list my tables in psql with:

```
\dt
```

For each table I type:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size('tablename') );
```

I get:

```
city_zip 0.048 MB
ntaboundaries 1.9 MB
zipcodeboundaries 2.4 MB
spatial_ref_sys 7.2 MB
```

What is going on? Is `pg_database_size()` telling me memory  allocated, not the storage memory used? Is there some other hidden location, like a log, that is hogging storage, and if so, how do I query the size of the logs?

Comment: Are you connected to the right database? Perhaps another database has all the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_total_relation_size()` sums up everything that belongs to a table, including bloat.

But `\dt` in psql does not list *all* tables of a database, it only includes schemas listed in the current `search_path`. Check with:

```
SHOW search_path;
```

System tables in `pg_catalog` are always excluded. And there may be additional schemas. To see **all tables** in the database:

```
\dt *.*
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERN)

> Whenever the pattern parameter is omitted completely, the `\d`
> commands display all objects that are visible in the current schema
> search path — this is equivalent to using `*` as the pattern. (An
> object is said to be visible if its containing schema is in the search
> path and no object of the same kind and name appears earlier in the
> search path. This is equivalent to the statement that the object can
> be referenced by name without explicit schema qualification.) To see
> all objects in the database regardless of visibility, use `*.*` as the pattern.

To see the biggest relations in your current database (make sure you are connected to the right one!):

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(c.oid)), c.oid::regclass, relkind
FROM   pg_class c
ORDER  BY pg_total_relation_size(c.oid) DESC
LIMIT  10;
```

I used `c.oid::regclass` because that automatically displays tables with schema-qualification where needed to be visible.

Note that indexes (`relkind = 'i'`) are included in the size of tables (`relkind = 'r'`), when asking with [`pg_total_relation_size()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE). But they are also listed separately in this list. Details about [`pg_class` in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html).

Related:

- [Measure the size of a PostgreSQL table row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/measure-the-size-of-a-postgresql-table-row/23933#23933)