# Find bloated tables and indexes in PostgreSQL without extensions

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have tables that change a lot during the day, lots of data is deleted, modified and inserted.

I suspect that the tables and indexes on those tables might be bloated.

I've seen that there are extensions options for PostgreSQL that can check this, but I would like to avoid creating extensions in my database.

How can I get this information (table/index is bloated) without having to use PostgreSQL extensions (eg.:pgstattuple), using only native PostgreSQL 12 features.?

Comment: You cannot do that without `pgstattuple`. Why do people so often ask questions like "how can I do X without Y", where Y is the proper solution for X?

Comment: `pgstattuple` is a "built-in" extension and available in every Postgres installation (at least installable in the same way as Postgres itself)

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/ioguix/pgsql-bloat-estimation/) or [here](https://github.com/keithf4/pg_bloat_check) or [here](https://askdba.org/weblog/2019/04/identifying-postgresql-bloat-and-fixing-it-without-downtime/) or [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Show_database_bloat)

Comment: [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/measure-the-size-of-a-postgresql-table-row/23933#23933) might be of help.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Postgres 13 added [index deduplication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-implementation.html#BTREE-DEDUPLICATION), which can compress indexes for duplicative data dramatically. Seems **all** four posted resources are outdated (at least) in this regard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have already been answered in the comments, it is best to use the standard `pgstattuple` extension.
If you do not want to use it, for some reason, you can see the **approximate** bloat values as follows:

```
-- Perform ANALYZE on your table
ANALYZE <table_name>;

-- Get the number of deadlines in your tables.
select schemaname,
relname,
pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(schemaname|| '.' || relname)) as size,
n_live_tup,
n_dead_tup,
CASE WHEN n_live_tup > 0 THEN round((n_dead_tup::float / 
n_live_tup::float)::numeric, 4) END AS dead_tup_ratio,
last_autovacuum,
last_autoanalyze
from pg_stat_user_tables
order by dead_tup_ratio desc NULLS LAST;
```

The higher the `dead_tup_ratio`, the higher the bloat of your table. But these are **approximate** data collected in the course of collecting statistics!
The best way to know for sure about bloat is to use the `pgstattuple` extension.

Comment: Shouldn't instead use the following formula to have the number of dead tuples above the total number of tuples: CASE WHEN n_live_tup > 0 THEN round((n_dead_tup::float /
dn_live_tup::float+dn_dead_tup::float)::numeric, 4) END AS dead_tup_ratio,