# Table with smaller data types seems to take more space on disk?

Tags: postgresql, disk-space, storage, postgresql-14

I have these two identical tables:

```
                  Table "public.region"
   Column    |   Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-------------+----------+-----------+----------+---------
 r_regionkey | integer      |           | not null | 
 r_name      | char(25)     |           |          | 
 r_comment   | char(152)     |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "region_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (r_regionkey)
```

and

```
                  Table "public.region2"
   Column    |   Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-------------+----------+-----------+----------+---------
 r_regionkey | smallint |           | not null | 
 r_name      | text     |           |          | 
 r_comment   | text     |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "region_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (r_regionkey)
```

I am using `smallint` and `text` in order to save space, but weirdly this is the result:

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('region'))
```

returns `8192 bytes` while

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('region2'))
```

returns `48 kB`.

Why is `region2` taking more space, even though I am using `smallint` instead of `integer` and `text` instead of `char(n)`?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12608013)

Comment: Assuming that they contain the same visible rows, it must be because it is bloated. Run `VACUUM (FULL)` on both tables and compare again. Avoiding `char` is good, but [always use `bigint` for artificial primary keys](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/uuid-serial-or-identity-columns-for-postgresql-auto-generated-primary-keys/#primary-key-data-type).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - if there are never going to be more than ~ 16k regions, the surely `SMALLINT` is superior to `BIGINT` as a PK?

Comment: @Vérace In a purist sense, and as far as storage space is concerned, yes. But for a small table, the difference is irrelevant, and I prefer to have a simple rule.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: For a small table the difference is irrelevant indeed. But those are often lookup tables referenced in *big* tables, with one or more indexes on them. Then the difference can matter, especially when multicolumn indexes get 50 % bigger with `bigint` ... So, `integer` typically makes sense. (`smallint` much less commonly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running `VACUUM FULL public.region;` and `VACUUM FULL public.region2;`, test again with:

```
SELECT pg_relation_size('public.region');
```

Three possible issues:

1. The obvious reason: table bloat from updates or deletes. Removed by `VACUUM FULL`.
2. Schema-qualified names ('public.region' instead of just 'region') makes sure you don't measure the wrong table in a different schema by accident. Probably not the case.
3. `pg_table_size()` includes auxiliary relation forks (files), which may be filled for one table, but not for the other. For your purpose, the more accurate test is with `pg_relation_size()`.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE)

> `pg_table_size` ( `regclass` ) → `bigint`
>
> Computes the disk space used by the specified table, excluding indexes
> (but including its TOAST table if any, free space map, and visibility
> map).

And:

> `pg_relation_size` ( *`relation`* `regclass` [, *`fork`* `text` ] ) →
> `bigint`
>
> Computes the disk space used by one “fork” of the specified relation.
> (Note that for most purposes it is more convenient to use the
> higher-level functions `pg_total_relation_size` or `pg_table_size`,
> which sum the sizes of all forks.) With one argument, this returns the
> size of the main data fork of the relation. The second argument can be
> provided to specify which fork to examine:
>
> - `main` returns the size of the main data fork of the relation.
> - `fsm` returns the size of the Free Space Map (see [Section 70.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-vm.html)) associated with the relation.
> - `vm` returns the size of the Visibility Map (see [Section 70.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-vm.html)) associated with the relation.
> - `init` returns the size of the initialization fork, if any, associated with the relation.

Since your example has no [TOAST table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html), only [`fsm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-fsm.html) and [`vm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-vm.html) make a difference. Those are typically negligible in size for bigger tables, but relevant for your minimal test. Both may go down to "0 bytes" after `VACUUM FULL`.

Test with more rows (thousands).

Related:

- [Measure the size of a PostgreSQL table row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/measure-the-size-of-a-postgresql-table-row/23933#23933)