# Very slow execution of a simple query

Tags: postgresql, explain

I try to create a report for my data, but it is really slow on a big table.

The table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE posts
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  project_id integer,
  moderation character varying(255),
  keyword_id integer,
  author_id integer,
  created_at timestamp without time zone,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone,
  server_id character varying(255),
  social_creation_time integer,
  social_id character varying(255),
  network character varying(255),
  mood character varying(255) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  url text,
  source_id integer,
  location character varying(255),
  subject_id integer,
  conversation_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT posts_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE INDEX index_posts_on_author_id ON posts (author_id);
CREATE INDEX index_posts_on_keyword_id ON posts (keyword_id);
CREATE INDEX index_posts_on_project_id_and_network_and_social_id 
    ON posts (project_id, network, social_id);
CREATE INDEX index_posts_on_project_id_and_social_creation_time 
    ON posts (project_id, social_creation_time DESC);
CREATE INDEX index_posts_on_server_id ON posts (server_id);
CREATE INDEX index_posts_on_social_id ON posts (social_id);
```

The query:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', timestamp 'epoch' 
           + (posts.social_creation_time * INTERVAL '1 second')) creating,
       network, 
       count(*) posts 
FROM posts 
WHERE posts.project_id = 7 
   AND (posts.moderation NOT IN ('junk','spam')) 
   AND (posts.social_creation_time BETWEEN 1391716800 AND 1392839999) 
GROUP BY network, creating 
ORDER BY creating
```

The count is 3940689.

Explain plan

```
 GroupAggregate  (cost=631282.11..671932.05 rows=338750 width=12) (actual time=22576.318..23826.124 rows=1776 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=631282.11..639750.85 rows=3387494 width=12) (actual time=22576.188..23438.485 rows=3536790 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (date_trunc('hour'::text, ('1970-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone + ((social_creation_time)::double precision * '00:00:01'::interval)))), network
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 92032kB
         ->  Seq Scan on posts  (cost=0.00..205984.62 rows=3387494 width=12) (actual time=29.542..1954.865 rows=3536790 loops=1)
               Filter: (((moderation)::text <> ALL ('{junk,spam}'::text[])) AND (social_creation_time >= 1391716800) AND (social_creation_time <= 1392839999) AND (project_id = 7))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 404218
 Total runtime: 23842.532 ms
(8 rows)

Time: 23860.876 ms
```

It's seq scan, but then I force use indexes it not help:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=815927.00..856583.47 rows=338804 width=12) (actual time=24634.378..25873.754 rows=1778 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=815927.00..824397.09 rows=3388039 width=12) (actual time=24634.243..25498.578 rows=3537295 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (date_trunc('hour'::text, ('1970-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone + ((social_creation_time)::double precision * '00:00:01'::interval)))), network
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 92048kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on posts  (cost=191020.29..390555.96 rows=3388039 width=12) (actual time=4074.171..5685.734 rows=3537295 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: (project_id = 7)
               Filter: (((moderation)::text <> ALL ('{junk,spam}'::text[])) AND (social_creation_time >= 1391716800) AND (social_creation_time <= 1392839999))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 67925
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_posts_on_project_id_and_network_and_social_id  (cost=0.00..190173.29 rows=3617164 width=0) (actual time=4054.817..4054.817 rows=3605225 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (project_id = 7)
 Total runtime: 25891.215 ms
```

An example row from the table:

```
   id   | project_id | moderation | keyword_id | author_id |         created_at         |         updated_at         | server_id | social_creation_time |    social_id    |  network  | mood |                url                 | source_id |      location      | subject_id | conversation_id
---
 204202 |          2 | pending    |            |    125845 | 2014-01-22 15:14:14.786454 | 2014-01-22 15:14:14.786454 | 20620977  |           1390318030 | -64193113_14905 | vkontakte |      | https://vk.com/wall-64193113_14905 |        64 | Россия, Черепаново |            |
```

** UPDATE **

real that help me is work_mem set to

my new plan:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=247145.17..254270.53 rows=356268 width=12) (actual time=2564.201..2564.731 rows=1853 loops=1)
    ->  Seq Scan on posts  (cost=0.00..220425.11 rows=3562675 width=12) (actual time=32.916..1914.618 rows=3729876 loops=1)
         Filter: (((moderation)::text <> ALL ('{junk,spam}'::text[])) AND (social_creation_time >= 1391716800) AND (social_creation_time <= 1392839999) AND (project_id = 7))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 501865
Total runtime: 2566.071 ms
```

**UPDATE #2**
I think create a integer column and save date like 20140220 (YYYMMDD). stackexchange, what you think, it performance gains?

PS: Sorry all for my bad english

Comment: Do you have any specific reason for storing the timestamps as unix epoch?  On the other hand, the `ORDER BY` is completely useless.  And you may win some time by setting `work_mem` to a higher value - I'd try 512 MB first.

Comment: Yes, you right, ORDER BY is unnecessary. work_mem and also help (thank you to Craig Ringer I don't now how set it for current request). But it's still slow. Think to try play with Materialized view

Comment: I think an appropriate index would help - besides suggested improvements on the configuration.

Comment: @ypercube: I expanded a bit on the index angle.

Comment: What is the cardinality of your table? (`SELECT count(*) FROM posts`) Which `WHERE` conditions would define a super-set of rows for your queries? What percentage of rows can be ruled out?

Comment: According to your execution plan your filters remove just 1/7th of all the rows -- a full scan of your table is going to be fastest. 2.5 seconds for aggregating 3 million rows is pretty good, in my books.

Comment: problem is that elasticsearch to near same job for 250ms (but in all table, no filtering)

Comment: You need to start both date & time, right? You can store this as Unix epoch as `integer` in bytes (with rollover in 2038...) rather than as a `timestamp` in 8 bytes, but I don't think it will win you that much performance. If you go down this route it will be micro-optimization, I think, and better combined with the suggestions that @ErwinBrandstetter makes. Also, are you on PostgreSQL 9.3?

Comment: yes, I use 9.3
now I create new column as I wrote in update 2, that make me simplyfy query to 

`SELECT creation_day, network, count(*) posts 
FROM "posts" 
WHERE "posts"."project_id" = 2 AND ("posts"."moderation" NOT IN ('junk','spam')) 
      AND ("posts"."creation_day" BETWEEN 20140217 AND 20140219) 
GROUP BY network, creation_day 
ORDER BY creation_day`

Comment: Be sure to use the [data type `date`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) for actual dates.

Comment: @erwin-brandstetter any performance reason not use int?

Comment: @LeonidBatizhevsky: For basic performance `date` is not better than `integer`. Both occupy 4 bytes. `date` is just another integer internally anyway, nowadays, and it is the natural type for dates. Input, output, date / time functions and optimized to deal with that kind of data. Doing stuff manually on top of `integer` values is regularly slower, and much more error-prone. Worst case would be to store a text representation, but you are not considering that anyway, AIU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
>      Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 92048kB
> ```

Throw more `work_mem` at the problem. Lots more. Try:

```
SET LOCAL work_mem = '300MB';
```

Be aware that if you're running it in lots of concurrent connections you could exhaust system RAM. So `SET` only in individual sessions.

Your row-count estimate on the aggregate is a bit dodgy (http://explain.depesz.com/s/RXbq) but not too bad. The killer seems to be that big sort.

Comment: thank you, after setting up work_mem to 300mb query runs at 6 seconds.

Comment: @LeonidBatizhevsky Also try creating an index on `(project_id, social_creation_time) WHERE (posts.moderation NOT IN ('junk','spam'))`

Comment: You may see in explain, that index not used because user aggregation in memory

Comment: This query not use indexes, I try to force it with Erwin's index, but used old index, not new

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the good advice by @Craig and @dezso:

#### Statistics

> The count is **3940689**.

Yet, your query plan says:

> ```
> Seq Scan on posts  (cost=0.00..205984.62 rows=**3387494** width=12)
> ```

And your count is based on a selection:

> ```
> Rows Removed by Filter: 404218
> ```

4344907 (3940689 + 404218) >> 3387494. Your **statistics are not up to date**. Something may be wrong with your [`autovacuum` settings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-autovacuum.html), which among other things runs `ANALYZE` automatically. Very bad for overall db performance. For the query at hand run before you retry anything:

```
ANALYZE posts
```

If you can afford a lock on the table for some time, run

```
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE posts
```

to clean house. [More here.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37028/postgresql-9-2-vacuum-returning-disk-space-to-operating-system/37032#37032)

#### Index

The numbers indicate your query uses about 90 % of all rows. Therefore, a sequential scan will be faster than any possible index scan - except for a [**covering index (index-only scan)**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37028/postgresql-9-2-vacuum-returning-disk-space-to-operating-system/37032#37032). Requires Postgres **9.2+**. Be sure to read the [Postgres Wiki on the topic](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans).

Since you only use two small columns out of a long list of columns, such an index would be smaller and faster. While being at it, and depending on your overall requirements, a tailored index like the following would squeeze out the maximum performance: a [*partial*, *functional*, *multicolumn*, *covering* index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes.html) - at some cost for write operations:

```
CREATE INDEX test_idx ON posts (
   date_trunc('hour', timestamp 'epoch' + social_creation_time * interval  '1 sec')
  ,network)
WHERE moderation NOT IN ('junk','spam')
AND   project_id = 7                         -- ??
AND   social_creation_time BETWEEN 1391716800 AND 1392839999 -- ??
```

Actual `WHERE` conditions depend on your actual requirements and need to be added in a more or less identical form to any query that wishes to use this index. Trim rows that are never used from the index. Only use conditions that eliminate more than a few rows, tailor a super-set of rows needed for your queries.

Generally, covering indexes work well for fairly static tables. Read the Wiki. A quick test:

```
SELECT relallvisible, relpages
FROM   pg_class
WHERE  oid = 'posts'::regclass
```

If `relallvisible` is not much smaller that `relpages`, chances are good. Be sure autovacuum is running properly before you try this.

I would also test without the functional aspect to see which is used / faster:

```
CREATE INDEX test_idx ON posts (social_creation_time, network)
WHERE moderation NOT IN ('junk','spam')
AND   project_id = 7                         -- ??
AND   social_creation_time BETWEEN 1391716800 AND 1392839999; -- ??
```

[A search for related answers dealing with a partial covering indexe.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpostgres%5D%20partial%20covering%20index)

#### Table layout

Finally, in your table definition `integer` and `text` columns interchange, bloating the table quite a bit due to **data alignment and padding**. More in this related answer:
[Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

I would recreate your table along these lines:

```
CREATE TABLE post (
  post_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  project_id integer,
  created_at timestamp,
  updated_at timestamp,
  keyword_id integer,
  author_id integer,
  source_id integer,
  subject_id integer,
  conversation_id integer,
  social_creation_time integer,

  server_id  text,   -- could be integer?
  social_id  text,
  moderation text,
  network    text,
  url        text,
  location   text,
  mood       text
);
```

Will be a bit smaller, helping overall performance.
[Why `text` instead of `varchar(255)`?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20974/should-i-add-an-arbitrary-length-limit-to-varchar-columns/21496#21496)

Comment: **Statistics** - after full acuum 
posts count - 4232198

501865 + 3562675 << 4232198

 ** Index ** I create index but it not used http://explain.depesz.com/s/Fl0

new statistics 0 |   100151

Comment: More micro-optimizations could be to use `smallint` for any IDs where less than 32K entries are expected but that depends on your data. I think project_id and server_id might be candidates for this.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of a partial, functional, multicolumn, covering index. Almost the only trick you haven't used yet is a non-btree index type, but that doesn't seem appropriate here!

Comment: @Colin'tHart: Micro-optimization with `smallint` is tricky. You really need to know what you are doing and it won't buy you much. Generally it's best to stick with `integer`, unless you have lots of columns with small numbers.

Comment: @LeonidBatizhevsky: The covering index should be used if you have fairly static data. I added a bit more concerning that.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter where did you learn all this stuff? I want to be just like you when I grow up haha