# Fixing table structure to avoid `Error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint`

Tags: postgresql, database-design, insert, auto-increment, sequence

I have a table which is created this way:

```
--
-- Table: #__content
--
CREATE TABLE "jos_content" (
  "id" serial NOT NULL,
  "asset_id" bigint DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
   ...
  "xreference" varchar(50) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

Later some rows are inserted specifying the id:

`INSERT INTO "jos_content" VALUES (1,36,'About',...)`

At a later point some records are inserted without id and they fail with the error:
`Error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint`.

Apparently the id got defined as a sequence:

[image]

Each failed insert increases the pointer in the sequence till it increments to a value that no longer exists and the queries succeed.

`SELECT nextval('jos_content_id_seq'::regclass)`

What is wrong with the table definition? What is the smart way to fix this?

Comment: In PostgreSQL, you don't need to quote column and table names if they're all lowercase.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your table definition.
<sub>(Except that I would use `jos_content_id` or something instead of the non-descriptive column name `id`.

And I probably would [use `text` instead of `varchar(50)`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20974/should-i-add-an-arbitrary-length-limit-to-varchar-columns/21496#21496).</sub>

Your `INSERT` statement is the problem.

With your `id` column defined as [`serial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL), you shouldn't insert manual values for `id`. Those may collide with the next value from the associated sequence.

Provide an explicit list of target columns (which is almost always a good idea for persisted `INSERT` statements) and **omit serial columns** completely.

```
INSERT INTO jos_content(asset_id, some_column, ...)
VALUES (36,'About',...);
```

If you need the value(s) of automatically generated column(s) immediately, use the [**`RETURNING`** clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html):

```
INSERT ...
RETURNING id;  -- possibly more
```

More details in this related answer on SO:

- [Increment value of a table ID for each INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635812/increment-value-of-a-table-id-for-each-insert/13636098#13636098)

If you have manual entries in `serial` columns that might conflict later, set your sequence to the current maximum `id` to **fix** this *once*:

```
SELECT setval('jos_content_id_seq', max(id))
FROM   jos_content;
```

Where `jos_content_id_seq` is the default name for a sequence owned by `jos_content.id`, which you already found in the column default. Seems to be `xhzt8_content_id_seq` in your case;

---

*Update:* A similar issue popped up on SO and I came up with a new solution:

- [Make Postgres choose the next minimal available id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28154950/939860)

Comment: Isn't text slower than varchar(50)?

Comment: @Rodrigo: Not in Postgres. There is a link above to more explanation: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21496/3684. Or here. http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89433/3684

Comment: The last test here <http://www.depesz.com/2010/03/02/charx-vs-varcharx-vs-varchar-vs-text/> convinced me that varchar(n) is faster for most fields where a restriction in size is convenient (people names, emails, addresses, species names, etc). Text is faster (or the same) if you won't check the length, it seems.