# Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, varchar

I have a legacy schema (disclaimer!) that uses a hash-based generated id for the primary key for all tables (there are many). An example of such an id is:

```
922475bb-ad93-43ee-9487-d2671b886479
```

There is no possible hope of changing this approach, however performance with index access is poor. Setting aside the myriad of reasons this might be, there is one thing I noticed that seemed less than optimal - despite all id values in all many tables being exactly 36 characters in length, the column type is `varchar(36)`, *not* `char(36)`.

Would altering the column types to fixed length `char(36)` offer any *significant* index performance benefits, beyond the very small increase in the number of entries per index page etc?

Ie does postgres perform much faster when dealing with fixed-length types than with variable length types?

Please don't mention the minuscule storage saving - that's not going be matter compared with the surgery required to make the change to the columns.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

No. **No gain at all**. [The manual explicitly states](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html):

> Tip: **There is no performance difference among these three types**, apart
> from increased storage space when using the blank-padded type, and a
> few extra CPU cycles to check the length when storing into a
> length-constrained column. While `character(n)` has performance
> advantages in some other database systems, there is no such advantage
> in PostgreSQL; in fact `character(n)` is usually the slowest of the
> three because of its additional storage costs. **In most situations `text`
> or `character varying` should be used instead**.

Bold emphasis mine.

`char(n)` is a largely outdated, useless type. Stick with `varchar(n)`. Without need to enforce a maximum length, `varchar` or `text` are a tiny bit faster, with fewer complications.

If all strings are exactly 36 characters in length, there is **no** storage saving either way, not even a minuscule one. Both have exactly the same size on disk and in RAM. You can test with [`pg_column_size()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE) (on an expression and on a table column).

And if all strings *must* have 36 characters, rather make it `text` with a `CHECK (length(col) = 36)` constraint enforcing *exact* length, not `varchar(36)` only enforcing max. length. See:

- [Any downsides of using data type “text” for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334221/939860)

You didn't ask for **other options**, but I'll mention two:

##### 1. [**`COLLATION`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html)

Unless you are running your DB with the ["C" collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/locale.html). Collation is often overlooked and possibly expensive. Since your strings don't seem to be meaningful in a natural language, there is probably no point in following `COLLATION` rules. Related:

- [How do I efficiently get "the most recent corresponding row"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/how-do-i-efficiently-get-the-most-recent-corresponding-row/49555#49555)
- [EXECUTE within function not using index?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82420/execute-within-function-not-using-index/82508#82508)

Extensive benchmark comparing (among other) the effect of `COLLATE "C"` on performance:

- [Slow query ordering by a column in a joined table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9908333/939860)

##### 2. [**UUID**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html)

Your string suspiciously looks like a UUID (32 hex digits separated by 4 delimiters in canonical way). It's much more efficient to store UUIDs as actual `uuid` data type: faster in multiple ways, and only occupies **16** bytes per UUID - as opposed to **37** bytes in RAM for either `char(36)` or `varchar(36)` (stored without delimiters, just the 32 defining characters), or **33** bytes on disk. But [alignment padding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/939860) would result in **40** bytes either way in many cases.) `COLLATION` is irrelevant for the `uuid` data type, too.

```
SELECT '922475bb-ad93-43ee-9487-d2671b886479'::uuid;
```

This may be helpful (last chapters):

- [Convert hex in text representation to decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8335376/939860)

See also:

- [What is the overhead for varchar(n)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125499/what-is-the-overhead-for-varcharn/125526#125526)
- [What is the optimal data type for an MD5 field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115271/what-is-the-optimal-postgresql-data-type-for-an-md5-field/115316#115316)

Comment: does this mean that a length constrained char/varchar(n) will spend CPU cycles in checking the constraint while the variable length text field would store the text separately in a less accessible way compared to char, who wins in this scenario and is this win even worth considering for say 10 million rows with a piece of text

Comment: @PirateApp: `char(n)` almost *never* wins in any respect. [Don't use it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334221/939860) The data types `text` and `varchar` (without length modifier) are binary compatible and share the same performance characteristics. There are historical reasons for *both* to coexist in Postgres. Internally, `text` is the "preferred" type among string types (which can influence function type resolution). The CPU cycles for enforcing `varchar(n)` barely matter. Use a length restriction when you *need* it. In the case at hand `uuid` is the real winner.

Comment: In the context of fixed length values (36 in this case), why does `character(n)` use *more* storage than `varchar(n)`. And what are the *additional* storage costs that make it *slower*? I assumed that `varchar(n)` uses *more* storage because it stores 1 byte of length info (for lengths < 256) and that `char(n)` may dispense with because the stored data length is baked into the column definition.