# Query that was working on MySQL is not working on PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, datatypes

I had the following query (with `bin_number` being a string) which was working on MySQL 5.5:

Postgres - was working on MySQL and doesn't work on PostgreSQL

```
SELECT "menu_items".* 
FROM "menu_items" 
WHERE ((header like '%red%' 
         or detail like '%red%' 
         or bin_number like '%red%') 
  and location_id='37' 
  and is_deleted=false and bin_number<>'') 
ORDER BY bin_number asc;
> 0 results   # should be 17
```

Postgres - works so issues with `and bin_number<>''`

```
SELECT "menu_items".* 
FROM "menu_items" 
WHERE ((header like '%red%' 
        or detail like '%red%' 
        or bin_number like '%red%') 
and location_id='37' 
and is_deleted=false) 
ORDER BY bin_number asc;
> 17 results
```

I tried changing `bin_number<>''` to `bin_number!=''` but that didn't make a difference.
Why is this not working?

edit 1

The bin_number in menu_items is declared as:

> bin_number | character varying(255) |  | extended |   |

Comment: What's the data type of `location_id`? Why is an integer in quotes?

Comment: bin_number is a string

Comment: I also don't understand "*Postgres - works*" vs. "*doesn't work on PostgreSQL*" what exactly is "*working*" and what exactly is "*not working*"

Comment: works == 17 results, not works == 0 results

Comment: the location_id is being done as a string since it is coming from a params hash which will be a string; standard practice

Comment: In the 2nd query, that "works", what are the 17 values of `bin_number` column? (The obvious reason why the 1st query returns 0 rows is that the 17 rows contain values in `bin_number` column that do not match the `bin_number <> ''` condition.)

Comment: Show us some values of `bin_number`.

Comment: Don't compare numbers and strings. Use proper numeric literals `37` is a number, `'37'` is a string.

Comment: @tblPhil It's legal in SQL to have an integer in quotes anyway.

Comment: Please provide proper information: "string" is not a data type. It should be obvious to provide the ***actual data type***. And  your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 3):

My educated guess (while proper information is missing): You declared `bin_number` as [**`character(n)`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html), `char(n)` or just `char` data type.

`character(n)` is an outdated, inefficient, weird data type, but defined in the SQL standard. `char` (without double quotes!) or `char(1)` are aliases for `character(1)`.

Typically you do **not** want to use it. It's a blank-padded data type where all strings containing **only blanks or nothing** (i.e. the empty string `''`) are considered identical. Effectively all of these are treated as empty strings because trailing blanks are considered insignificant.

```
SELECT '  '       <> '';  -- TRUE
SELECT '  '::text <> '';  -- TRUE (identical, because text is default
SELECT '  '::char <> '';  -- FALSE (!!)
```

Use [`varchar` or `text`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html) instead.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb/212) with a matrix of comparisons.

More:

- [Compare varchar with char](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17333258/939860)
- [Any downsides of using data type “text” for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17333258/939860)
- [Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89429/would-index-lookup-be-noticeably-faster-with-char-vs-varchar-when-all-values-are/89433#89433)

It's either that, or you have `NULL` values in the column where you had empty strings in MySQL. Either way, the table definition (`\d tbl` in psql) in the question and some sample values would allow answers instead of speculation.

Comment: My guess was that he has nulls. Postgres strictness vs. MySQL willingness to absorb data without errors, could very well have same statements resulting in different data in the tables between the two dbms. But the `'  '::char <> ''` resulting in false is quite probable reason, too.

Comment: thx, you were right regarding character (have added the output from \d+ menu_items from psql. Reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694273/changing-a-column-type-to-longer-strings-in-rails makes me think I should be using these. Might try to hotfix for this situation for time being though. thx again

Comment: @timpone: This seems to be a misunderstanding. `character varying(255)`  is the same as `varchar(n)` *not* `character(n)`. And `varchar` is just fine ([except hat the modifier 255 is typically based on another misunderstanding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558650/refactor-foreign-key-to-fields/24560486#24560486)) and cannot explain the problem. [Read the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html) and check for NULL values ...

Comment: thx Erwin - I'm going back to this being a data issue; this has been a bit of a big migration that went mostly well but I really appreciate your help and insights.

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one case where `bin_number <> ''` is handled differently in MySQL and PostgreSQL. It's when the string only contains spaces. Check out [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8474327/1288184) that sheds a light to the MySQL side of things.

PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT '' <> ' '
true
```

MySQL:

```
SELECT '' <> ' '
false
```

Usually when the statement contains `LIKE` the difference happens because keyword `LIKE` is handled differently in MySQL and PostgreSQL. In PostgreSQL you have to use `ILIKE` to get case-insensitive pattern matching.

[MySQL Documentation - 3.3.4.7 Pattern Matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html):

> SQL patterns are case-insensitive by default

[PostgreSQL Documentation -  9.7.1. LIKE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE):

> The key word ILIKE can be used instead of LIKE to make the match case-insensitive according to the active locale. This is not in the SQL standard but is a PostgreSQL extension.

Comment: thx - I think the like statement is fine, the second result returns the anticipated 17 results using like.

Comment: Yeah, sorry didn't read it thoroughly enough. I added one case where that bin_number comparison is handled differently. If it's not about that we would then need the 17 values returned as ypercube mentioned.

Comment: And actually that can't be the problem as PostgreSQLs more strict comparison actually returns `true` more often. Well, we'll wait to see those 17 values.

Comment: You may be on the right track, let's try the opposite direction ...