# Index on column with data type citext not used

Tags: postgresql, index, pattern-matching, case-sensitive

In PostgreSQL 9.4, with following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    junk CHAR(1000)
);

INSERT INTO people(id, name)
 SELECT generate_series(1,100000), md5(random()::text);

CREATE INDEX ON people (name text_pattern_ops);
```

if I search by name, the index is used:

```
test=# explain analyze select id, name from people where name like 'a%';
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on people  (cost=248.59..1160.92 rows=6061 width=37) (actual time=2.412..8.340 rows=6271 loops=1)
   Filter: (name ~~ 'a%'::text)
   Heap Blocks: exact=834
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on people_name_idx  (cost=0.00..247.08 rows=6266 width=0) (actual time=2.123..2.123 rows=6271 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((name ~>=~ 'a'::text) AND (name ~<~ 'b'::text))
 Planning time: 0.600 ms
 Execution time: 8.991 ms
```

But if I replace `TEXT` with `CITEXT`:

```
CREATE EXTENSION CIText;

CREATE TABLE people (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name CITEXT,
    junk CHAR(1000)
);
```

The index is not used anymore:

```
test=# explain analyze select id, name from people where name like 'a%';
                                                QUERY PLAN                                                 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on people  (cost=0.00..2084.00 rows=500 width=36) (actual time=5.700..152.572 rows=6305 loops=1)
   Filter: (name ~~ 'a%'::citext)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 93695
 Planning time: 0.764 ms
 Execution time: 153.046 ms
```

According to [`CITEXT` PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/citext.html), the behavior should be as with `TEXT`:

> Otherwise, it behaves almost exactly like text.

How can I tell PostgreSQL to use the index?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Index usage with `text_pattern_ops` (as well as with the default operator class when using the `C` locale) depends on the *binary representation* of character data. `citext` stores original values with the case preserved, so there *must* be a problem with that ...

Like [you commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105244/index-on-colum-with-data-type-citext-not-used/105250?noredirect=1#comment192332_105250), the actual reason is [burried in collation support](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/12187.1307391240@sss.pgh.pa.us).

Either way, `citext` or `text`, you can make it work with an expression index:

```
CREATE INDEX people_name_idx ON people (lower(name) text_pattern_ops);
```

And a corresponding query:

```
SELECT id, name FROM people WHERE lower(name) LIKE 'abc%';
```

Note that `lower(name)` returns data type `text`, even when feeding it `citext`.

Alternatively, you could use a trigram index, which is more expensive to maintain, but also offers more capabilities:

- [How is LIKE implemented?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/how-is-like-implemented/10856#10856)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)

Aside: your test case is suboptimal because your dummy values are all lower case to begin with and the pattern `'a%'` is often not selective enough to use an index *at all*. And [`char(1000)` doesn't make sense](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96551/query-that-was-working-on-mysql-is-not-working-on-postgresql/96559#96559) (even though irrelevant to the test).

Comment: It seems that the LIKE index optimization doesn't work with `CITEXT`:
http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/27270.1364700924@sss.pgh.pa.us

There is an entry on PostgreSQL's TODO: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo (just search for the previous link)

In my case, search for case insensitive left anchored patterns, the use of `CITEXT` doesn't seem to provide any benefit.
I'm reverting the column type to `TEXT` and using a functional index. About the triagam index, since some of my search patterns have only one or two characters ('a%' or 'ab%'), probably the use a B-tree index performs better.

Comment: @JoséLuis: For only left anchored searches a btree `text_pattern_ops` index performs best in any case. A trigram index would be relevant to do more than that (full-text searches, similarity, ...). It *does* work for `'a%'` or `'ab%'`, too. The simple trick in the implementation is to prepend two space characters before chipping off trigrams (but that's transparent for the user).

Comment: @JoséLuis I went through similar case (same to the one which you posted). CITEXT not taking indexes even in 10.4.