# How to use an array as argument to a VARIADIC function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, functions, array, parameter, case-sensitive

I am trying to make a case-insensitive version of `json_extract_path_text()`, using the `citext` module.

I would like this to be a simple wrapper around the built-in function, the only difference being that it accepts `citext` as the first parameter instead of `json`. I want this to be a straight pass-through to the native implementation, just with a type conversion beforehand. Here's what I have so far:

```
create extension citext;

create or replace function json_extract_path_text ( string citext, variadic params text[]) RETURNS text IMMUTABLE AS
$$
    BEGIN
        SELECT json_extract_path_text(string::json, params);
    END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

This doesn't work properly, however, because of the type mis-match:

> ```
> ERROR:  function json_extract_path_text(json, text[]) does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT json_extract_path_text(string::json, params)
>                ^
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> QUERY:  SELECT json_extract_path_text(string::json, params)
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function json_extract_path_text(citext,text[]) line 3 at SQL statement
> ```

I've tried hacking around a solution using dynamic string construction and `EXECUTE`, but this is a real hassle and I feel like there must be a cleaner way to pass `VARIADIC` params through to the inner function. I can't see any obvious way to do so, however. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pass the array ***as is*** using the `VARIADIC` key word in the call:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_extract_path_text(string citext, VARIADIC params text[])
  RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
'SELECT json_extract_path_text(string::json, VARIADIC params)';
```

Call:

```
SELECT json_extract_path_text('{"f1":{"f2":1,"f3":"foo"}}', VARIADIC '{f1, f3}');
```

> ```
>  json_extract_path_text
> ----------------------
>  foo
> ```

`PARALLEL SAFE` for Postgres 9.6 or later.

[The manual on `VARIADIC`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS)

> Sometimes it is useful to be able to pass an already-constructed array
> to a variadic function; this is particularly handy when one variadic
> function wants to pass on its array parameter to another one. You can
> do that by specifying `VARIADIC` in the call:
>
> ```
> SELECT mleast(VARIADIC ARRAY[10, -1, 5, 4.4]);
> ```

More details:

- [Select rows such that names match elements of input array for pgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17978831/939860)

To be clear: Inside the function, the `VARIADIC` parameter is just another array, nothing special about it. `VARIADIC` being used in two separate function *definitions* makes the case a bit confusing. The solution is to use the same keyword `VARIADIC` for a related but different purpose in the function *call*. Don't get confused even more.

Aside: Do not quote the language name, it's an identifier.

#### Case-insensitive version with `citext`?

> I am trying to make a case-insensitive version of `json_extract_path_text()`, using the citext module.

While the above function *works*, it's not case-insensitive at all. `citext` preserves original input, which is restored with the cast to `text` (or `json`) and can be mixed-case.

I would not use `citext` to begin with. Various corner case problems:

- [Index on column with data type citext not used](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105244/index-on-column-with-data-type-citext-not-used)

For your purpose I suggest calling the built-in [`json_extract_path_text()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) with `lower(citext_value)`, which returns lower-case `text`, and lower-case the 2nd parameter ("path elements") as well, to make it actually case-insensitive:

```
SELECT json_extract_path_text(lower('{"F1":{"f2":1,"f3":"foo"}}'::citext)::json
                            , VARIADIC lower('{f1, F3}')::text[]);
```

Note the cast to `text[]` after `lower()`.

Comment: This is great stuff, but I can't seem to get VARIADIC to work in the following test case: `SELECT jsonb_build_array('A', VARIADIC array_agg(value)) FROM jsonb_array_elements_text('["B","C"]'::JSONB)`, any idea why?

Comment: You are effectively calling `SELECT jsonb_build_array('A', VARIADIC '{B,C}'::text[])`, but `jsonb_build_array()` expects *either* a list of values, *or* a single array following the keyword `VARIADIC`. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, there are various solutions. Please ask a new question about it if anything is still unclear. You can always link to this one for context.