# Postgres bypassing index with IN clause with 100+ values?

Tags: postgresql, index, execution-plan, performance, postgresql-performance

I came across this [on another forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-users/y9sVr9Pbr-o/Z3b9WiJmBwAJ):

> PG has a limit of 100 for values in `IN` queries after which the index on said column is not used. For ex: a typical `SELECT ... WHERE IN (...)` query on the PK will be turned into a full table scan if the IN list exceeds 100.

I wasn't able to find anything about this.  Does PG have such a limit (I imagine so), and if so, what is the limit?

I know there are times where having a large subselect would be better used in a temp table, but it would be helpful to have knowledge of where the cutoff is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick test proves there is no hard-wired limit - for either variant of the `IN` construct, the one taking a *set* and the one taking a *list*:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7f9c1bea010cd9020b175e109b5a6a47)*

See how the index is scanned for *103* elements?

Related:

- [Optimizing a Postgres query with a large IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91247/optimizing-a-postgres-query-with-a-large-in/91539#91539)

There is a **related limit**: a `VARIADIC` function takes a maximum of 100 individual parameters. Beyond that one needs to pass an array ...

- [Efficiently return two aggregated arrays from a m:n table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204688/efficiently-return-two-aggregated-arrays-from-a-mn-table/204722#204722)

The only cases where a temporary table regularly improves performance is when you create useful indexes on the intermediary result before proceeding. Else, temp tables are typically (much) slower for this.

Comment: I get different index use when replacing the in clause by where <some subquery> is (not) null. This seems to bring about index use where in does not. Applies to finding missing elements in two large similar tables. Postgresql 11.14.