# How to prepend an element to a JSON array?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, json, plpgsql, array

I have a plpgsql function in PostgreSQL 9.6, which at some point has a `text` variable `_x` (guaranteed to not be NULL) and another variable `_y` which is a `JSONB` array of text (which might be empty).

How can I prepend the value of `_x` to the array `_y`?

I was trying to do it like this:

```
SELECT jsonb_build_array(_x, VARIADIC array_agg(value))
FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(_y)
INTO _y;
```

which is wrong. I was trying to use info about `VARIADIC` from [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/158088/113296).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burns down to a simple solution:

```
_y := to_jsonb(ARRAY[_x]) || _y;
```

This is [concatenating two jsonb arrays with the `||` operator.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE). You need to wrap the simple `text` value `_x` into a `jsonb` array for this. There are various way, `to_jsonb(ARRAY[_x])` is one.

Or even just:

```
_y := to_jsonb(_x) || _y;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE)

> The `||` operator concatenates the elements at the top level of each of
>   its operands. [...]

So this happens to work for element-to-array concatenation as well.

---

You *could* unnest the array and reconstruct it (like you were trying), but that's more expensive. And might be tricky since a JSON array can hold elements of various types, unlike a Postgres array. (Which would not be a problem for your *JSONB array of text*.)

Your attempt failed because ([as commented at the related answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158078/how-to-use-an-array-as-argument-to-a-variadic-function-in-postgresql/158088#comment440548_158088)), [`jsonb_build_array()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) expects a list of values, which can be replaced with a *single* array following the keyword `VARIADIC` - but not with a single element, followed by `VARIADIC` *array*.

Comment: How dare they make it that easy!

Comment: Outrageous indeed!