# Can I change CITEXT columns to VARCHAR without encountering any surprise difficulties?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, citext

I went overboard on CITEXT columns on a particularly large table in my application. I would like to back some of these out as it's confusing how to trigger lookups on the desired indexes.

My question is, can I do this without encountering any major difficulties? And if I change this, do I need to rebuild any indexes on those fields?

Will there be any space gains from moving in this direction?

Case-insensitive queries are not necessary on these columns.

I have counts against this table that are predicated on 2 columns, and these counts are taking over an hour. The table has 60 columns.

I am using Postgres 10.6.

I'm primarily interested in whether indexes need to be rebuilt if they contain a column that has changed from CITEXT to VARCHAR.

Comment: Not enough details. Do you need case insensitive searches or case sensitive or both? What queries do you have now and what problem do you face with them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will there be any space gains from moving in this direction?

No. `citext` and `text` (or `varchar`) occupy the same space on disk and in RAM.

> Case-insensitive queries are not necessary on these columns.

Then there is no point to use `citext`.

> I have counts against this table that are predicated on 2 columns, and these counts are taking over an hour. The table has 60 columns.

`count()` is not affected by `citext` vs. `text` (or `varchar`) at all. "60 columns" might be something to look into. No problem if you actually need all of them - but do you? And are you using proper data types etc.

> I'm primarily interested in whether indexes need to be rebuilt if they contain a column that has changed from CITEXT to VARCHAR.

Indexes involving the column are converted automatically. (This can mean rebuilding indexes.) [The manual on `ALTER TABLE`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#id-1.9.3.35.5)

> `SET DATA TYPE`
>
> This form changes the type of a column of a table. Indexes and simple
> table constraints involving the column will be automatically converted
> to use the new column type by reparsing the originally supplied
> expression.

It can fail when involving expressions that don't work for the new type (for expression or partial indexes). You have to drop such indexes and recreate them in adapted form after the change.

Personally, I stay away from `citext` after mixed experiences. Consider the [limitations discussed in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/citext.html#id-1.11.7.17.9).

Comment: what is the darkside of citext? I really like it for case-insensitive apps. Expression indexes on lower/upper seem so ugly...

Comment: @filiprem: I had troubles with collation and indexes. The chapter [`Limitations` in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/citext.html#id-1.11.7.17.7) sums it up nicely. Found this with a quick search: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/105250/3684. I am not advising against it, just had mixed experiences: the minor performance gain did not seem worth the added complications.