# Self-JOIN with occurrence count

Tags: postgresql, select

I use PostgreSQL 9.4 and I have a table called `certificates` containing the following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE certificates (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    common_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    state varchar(255),
    expires_on date,
);

CREATE INDEX index_certificates_on_common_name ON certificates (common_name);
CREATE INDEX index_certificates_on_expires_on ON certificates (expires_on);
```

I'd like to fetch all the certificates that have not been renewed yet, which means all the certificates that

1. don't have another certificate matching the `common_name` OR
2. have another certificate matching `common_name`, but the `state` is not issued or `expires_on` is past.

I created the following query. It works, but I wonder if it can be optimized to be more efficient.

```
SELECT
    C.*
FROM
    certificates as C
WHERE
    C.expires_on - 30 <= 'date-of-today' AND
    (
        SELECT COUNT(id) 
        FROM 
            certificates AS N 
        WHERE 
            certificates.common_name = N.common_name AND
            N.expires_on > certificates.expires_on 
            AND N.state = 'issued'
    ) = 0;
```

Specifically, my concern is the nested query that I believe is run once for each record in C.

I tried by self-joining the table but the resulting query may return duplicates (e.g. if a certificate has 2 or more renewals) and I feel like using `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` may not be the best option.

```
SELECT C.id, N.id
FROM 
    certificates AS C LEFT JOIN certificates AS N ON C.common_name = N.common_name
WHERE
    (C.expires_on - 30 <= 'date-of-today') AND
    (N.id IS NULL OR (N.state = 'issued' AND N.expires_on > C.expires_on));
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two major improvements:

```
SELECT *
FROM   certificates c
WHERE  c.expires_on <= current_date + 30  -- sargable!
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   certificates
   WHERE  common_name = c.common_name
   AND    expires_on  > c.expires_on
   AND    state = 'issued'
   );
```

1. Make the first predicate [**sargable**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable), so that an index can be used.
2. You second condition is that no qualifying row exists. So **don't count**, that would be expensive because Postgres has to scan all rows unconditionally. Use a `NOT EXISTS` anti-semi-join. Postgres can use an index again to quickly verify non-existence and can stop looking further as soon as the first qualifying row has been found. Typically much faster (depending on data distribution). There are several related techniques possible for this:

   - [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860)

Ideally, you have at least two indexes:

1. on `(expires_on)`:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON certificates (expires_on);
   ```
2. A partial multicolumn index.

   ```
   CREATE INDEX foo ON certificates (common_name, expires_on DESC)
   WHERE  state = 'issued';
   ```

If `state = 'issued'` is true for most rows, then adding the condition to the index won't help.

#### Answer to additional question in comment

If the number of days for tolerance is variable and stored as `integer` with each row, use a **[functional index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html)**:

```
CREATE INDEX ON certificates ((expires_on + expiring_days));
```

And adapt the query accordingly:

```
SELECT *
FROM   certificates c
WHERE  expires_on + expiring_days <= current_date  -- can use index
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   certificates
   WHERE  common_name = c.common_name
   AND    expires_on  > c.expires_on
   AND    state = 'issued'
   );
```

---

Aside: A column like `state` typically only allows a couple of distinct values. If so, it's a candidate for normalization: add a table `certificate_state` listing allowed values and use `state_id int REFERENCES state` in the main table. Just like outlined here:

- [Low cardinality fields: integer or string](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118695/low-cardinality-fields-integer-or-string/118954#118954)