# Index not being used in SELECT query

Tags: postgresql, database-design, index, performance, postgresql-performance

I have a table of about 3.25M rows with the follow format in Postgres 9.4.1

```
CREATE TABLE stats
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    type character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    "references" jsonb NOT NULL,
    path jsonb,
    data jsonb,
    "createdAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT stats_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
);
```

The `type` is a simple string no longer than 50 characters.

The `references` column is an object with an list of key values. Basically any list of simple key values, and only ever 1 level deep, the values are always strings. It could be

```
{
    "fruit": "plum"
    "car": "toyota"
}
```

or it could be

```
{
    "project": "2532"
}
```

The `createdAt` timestamp is not always generated from the database (but it will by default if a value isn't supplied)

I'm currently using the table with only testing data. In this data every row has a `project` key as a reference. So there are 3.25M rows with a project key. There are exactly 400,000 distinct values for the `project` reference. There are only 5 distinct values for the `type` field, this would probably be no more than a few hundred in production.

So I'm trying to index the table to perform the following query quickly:

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (MAX("createdAt") - MIN("createdAt"))) 
FROM
  stats
WHERE
  stats."references"::jsonb ? 'project' AND
  (
    stats."type" = 'event1' OR
    (
      stats."type" = 'event2' AND
      stats."createdAt" > '2015-11-02T00:00:00+08:00' AND
      stats."createdAt" < '2015-12-03T23:59:59+08:00'
    )
  )
GROUP BY stats."references"::jsonb->> 'project'
```

The query returns the time distance between two events based on two stats rows that have the same reference. In this case `project`. There is only ever 1 row for each `type` and selected `reference` value, but there may also be no rows in which case the result returned is 0 (this is averaged out later in a different part of a larger query).

I've created an index on the `createdAt` `type` and `references` columns but the query execution plan appears to be doing a full scan instead.

The index

```
CREATE INDEX "stats_createdAt_references_type_idx"
    ON stats
    USING btree
    ("createdAt", "references", type COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

Execution plan:

```
 HashAggregate  (cost=111188.31..111188.33 rows=1 width=38) 
                (actual time=714.499..714.499 rows=0 loops=1)
   Group Key: ("references" ->> 'project'::text)
      ->  Seq Scan on stats  (cost=0.00..111188.30 rows=1 width=38) 
                             (actual time=714.498..714.498 rows=0 loops=1)
          Filter: (
              (("references" ? 'project'::text) 
               AND ((type)::text = 'event1'::text)) OR 
              (((type)::text = 'event2'::text) 
               AND ("createdAt" > '2015-11-02 05:00:00+13'::timestamp with time zone) 
               AND ("createdAt" < '2015-12-04 04:59:59+13'::timestamp with time zone)))

Rows Removed by Filter: 3258680
Planning time: 0.163 ms
Execution time: 714.534 ms
```

I'm really not that clued up on indexing and query execution plans so if someone could point me in the right direction that'd be great.

*Edit*

As noted by Erwin, it appears as though even if i did have correct indexes, a table scan would still occur as the portion of the table returned from the query is very large. Does this mean that for this set of data this is the fastest query time i can get? Im assuming if i added 60M more unrelated rows without a project reference, it might use an index (if i had the correct indexes), but i dont see how that could speed up the query by adding more data. Maybe im missing something.

Comment: Did you try an index on `(type, created_at, references)` ?

Comment: @YperSillyCubeᵀᴹ I'm just going through now and trying out some indexes so I'll try that one out next.

Comment: No that one slowed it down to 26 seconds unfortunately :/

Comment: Oh, I misread the WHERE condition. Are you aware that the condition is equivalent to:? `WHERE (stats."references"::jsonb ? 'project' AND
  stats."type" = 'event1') OR
  (stats."type" = 'event2' AND
    stats."createdAt" > '2015-11-02T00:00:00+08:00' AND
    stats."createdAt" < '2015-12-03T23:59:59+08:00')`

Comment: Please provide your *actual* table definition showing exact data types and all constraints: a valid `CREATE TABLE` script or what you get with `\d stats` in psql. And *always* your version of Postgres. How many rows with a key `references ->> 'project'` and how many distinct values for `references ->> 'project'`?

Comment: @YperSillyCubeᵀᴹ No I wasn't aware! Good spotting, I'll fix that up. I'm only running test data at the moment so almost every row has a project reference, which is why I didn't spot it.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I've updated the table schema. Postgres version 9.4.1. 3.25M rows with 'project' reference. 400k distinct values. Only 5 distinct values at the moment for the type field, would probably be no more than a few hundred in production.

Comment: @JamesHay: That information should also go into the *question*. And I assume you'll fix your query, too? And are you really satisfied with any row having a `'project'` key? Or did you really want to restrict to a given value as well? Like `{"project": "2532"}`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I've added the information into the original question, and fixed the query. Yes I am satisfied with that. I'm specifically trying to find the date difference for all projects or any other reference key in future queries. However the value would be required too if I were say trying to find infromation about `{"project": "2532"}` in another query, which I almost definitely will be later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your current explanation **indexes are not going to help much** (if at all) with your current query.

> So there are 3.25M rows with a project key.

That's also the *total* number of rows, so this predicate is `true` for (almost) *every* row ... and not selective at all. But there is no useful index for the `jsonb` column `"references"`. Including it in the *btree* index on `("createdAt", "references", type)` is just pointless.

Even if you had a generally more useful GIN index on `"reference"` like:

```
CREATE INDEX stats_references_gix ON stats USING gin ("references");
```

... Postgres would still have [no useful statistics about individual keys inside the `jsonb` column.](http://akorotkov.github.io/blog/2015/09/07/jsonb_statistics/)

---

> There are only 5 distinct values for the `type`

Your query selects all of one type and an unknown fraction of another type. That's an estimated **20 - 40 % of all rows**. A sequential scan is most certainly going to be fastest plan. Indexes start to make sense for *around 5 % of all rows or less*.

To test, you can force a possible index by setting *for debugging purposes in your session*:

```
SET enable_seqscan = off;
```

Reset with:

```
RESET enable_seqscan;
```

You'll see slower queries ...

---

You group by project values:

> `GROUP  BY "references"->> 'project'`

And:

> There are exactly 400,000 distinct values for the project reference.

That's 8 rows per project on average. Depending on value frequencies we still have to retrieve an estimated 3 - 20 % of all rows if we only picked min and max per project in a LATERAL subquery ...

Try this index, it makes more sense than what you have now:

```
CREATE INDEX stats_special_idx ON stats (type, ("references" ->> 'project'), "createdAt")
WHERE "references" ? 'project';
```

Postgres might still fall back to a sequential scan ...

More might be done with a normalized schema / more selective criteria / a smarter query that only picks min and max `"createdAt"` ...

#### Query

I would write your query like this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (MAX("createdAt") - MIN("createdAt"))) 
FROM   stats
WHERE  "references" ? 'project'
AND   (type = 'event1' OR
       type = 'event2'
   AND "createdAt" >= '2015-11-02 00:00:00+08:00'  -- I guess you want this
   AND "createdAt" <  '2015-12-04 00:00:00+08:00'
      )
GROUP  BY "references"->> 'project';  -- don't cast
```

#### Notes

- Don't cast here:

  `stats."references"::jsonb ? 'project'`

  The column is `jsonb` already, you gain nothing. If the predicate *was* selective, index usage might be prohibited by the cast.
- Your predicates on `"createdAt"` are probably *incorrect* at lower and upper bound. To include whole days consider my suggested alternative.
- `references` is a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html), so you have to always double-quote it. Don't use it as identifier. Similar for double-quoted CaMeL-case names like `"createdAt"` either. Allowed, but error prone, needless complication.
- `type`

  > `type character varying(255) NOT NULL,`
  >
  > The type is a simple string no longer than 50 characters.
  >
  > There are only 5 distinct values for the type field, this would probably be no more than a few hundred in production.

  None of this seems to make sense.

  - [`varchar(255)` in itself hardly ever makes any sense](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24560486/939860). 255 characters is an arbitrary limit without significance in Postgres.
  - If it's no longer than 50 chars, then the limit of 255 makes even less sense.
  - In a properly normalized design you would have a small `integer` column `type_id` (referencing a small `type` table) which occupies only 4 bytes per row and makes indexes smaller and faster.
- Ideally, you would have a `project` table, listing all projects and another small integer FK column `project_id` in `stats`. Would make any such query faster. And for selective criteria, *much* faster queries would be possible - even without the suggested normalization. Along these lines:
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer. Noted on all of the above, naming conventions, date predicates, unecessary casting etc. I guess i've thrown myself off by using bad test data. On average the rows with project as a reference would be around 5 - 10 % of the table. I dont think the specialized index would work as the "references" dont actually point to anything else in the databse, theyre used purely as a way to tie rows together for various queries, and the key (project in this case) is user defined

Comment: Also regarding varchar it was automatically generated by a model definition using sequelize. Ive previously only worked with SQL server so thats the reason I wasnt aware of that problem. I will see if i can update the schema to use text.

Comment: @JamesHay: There is no problem with `varchar(n)` per se. But unlike SQL Server, there is also no magic benefit for limiting to `varchar(255)`. More: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89433/3684. Sequelize may be optimized for SQL Server ...