# Index by subkey in jsonb

Tags: postgresql, index, json, postgresql-9.6

I have a table `payment` with a `jsonb` column `application`. It contains payments and the total amount for one or more tours. For example, a parent can pay 1000 $ for all his family, e.g. 4 children and his wife. Then one row in `payment` contains 6 records in the `jsonb` field `application`, describing the tour and the customer.

```
[
   {
    "tour_id":
      {
        "id":"d61802ff-3eec-4a72-97ca-832f51b96bf0","name":"Paris  2018"
      },
      "amount":"500.00",
      "customer_id":
          {
             "id":"f492b26d-d260-4bcb-8e96-6532fdf38665",
             "name":"OBAMA John"
          },
     "id":"5cd8338c-15c2-48c5-b305-9e172bb33a9a"
   },
   {
    "tour_id":
      {
        "id":"a52d38d4-9bfb-4ffa-1122-e536f04b0c60","name":"London  2018"
      },
      "amount":"500.00",
      "customer_id":
          {
             "id":"f492b26d-d260-4bcb-8e96-6532fdf38665",
             "name":"OBAMA John"
          },
     "id":"5cd8338c-15c2-48c5-b305-9e172bb33a9a"
   },
]
```

My id is unique in all the postgres database, I'm using UUID v4. Which is the best way to index this id? Really the `name` is redundant here, because I have a table for customers and tours, and I could just record the id:

```
[
   {
    "tour_id":"d61802ff-3eec-4a72-97ca-832f51b96bf0",
    "amount":"500.00",
    "customer_id":"f492b26d-d260-4bcb-8e96-6532fdf38665",
    "id":"5cd8338c-15c2-48c5-b305-9e172bb33a9a"
   },
   (...more elements)
```

But I'd like to get advise on the best indexing strategy (or alternative solutions).

Comment: I am still not sure which `id` you want to index exactly. There are several different fields of that name ... And please always declare your Postgres version.

Comment: it's postgres 9.6  , I'm going to translate my form so you can understand better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A jsonb GIN index with the `jsonb_path_ops` operator class would be an option.

But to just index (multiple) `application #>> '{*, tour_id, id}')` values per `jsonb` field (pseudocode, the `*` is illegal), I would write a tiny, `IMMUTABLE` SQL function to extract and cast the UUID fields to an UUID array (`uuid[]`) - and create an expression GIN index on *that*. Should be considerably ***smaller*** and hence faster:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_extract_tour_ids(jsonb)
  RETURNS uuid[] AS
$func$
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT (jsonb_array_elements($1) #>> '{tour_id, id}')::uuid)
$func$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

What was missing in my original answer: there is no GIN operator class for `uuid[]`, yet (up to Postgres 10). [See this thread on pgsql-hackers.](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CADCw5QZctww5Q1MiTEx9OtOhT4g421Ftds%3D1MtTepqM2hLnrCQ%40mail.gmail.com#CADCw5QZctww5Q1MiTEx9OtOhT4g421Ftds=1MtTepqM2hLnrCQ@mail.gmail.com)

**Update:** Starting with Postgres 11, the [additional module btree_gin](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gin.html) provides the missing operator class.

You have to create it yourself (once per database):

```
CREATE OPERATOR CLASS _uuid_ops DEFAULT 
   FOR TYPE _uuid USING gin AS 
   OPERATOR 1 &&(anyarray, anyarray), 
   OPERATOR 2 @>(anyarray, anyarray), 
   OPERATOR 3 <@(anyarray, anyarray), 
   OPERATOR 4 =(anyarray, anyarray), 
   FUNCTION 1 uuid_cmp(uuid, uuid), 
   FUNCTION 2 ginarrayextract(anyarray, internal, internal), 
   FUNCTION 3 ginqueryarrayextract(anyarray, internal, smallint, internal, internal, internal, internal), 
   FUNCTION 4 ginarrayconsistent(internal, smallint, anyarray, integer, internal, internal, internal, internal), 
   STORAGE uuid;
```

Note ([quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createopclass.html)):

> The user who defines an operator class becomes its owner. Presently,
>   the creating user must be a superuser.

See:

- [PostgreSQL GIN index on array of uuid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959735/postgresql-gin-index-on-array-of-uuid)

*Then* create the index:

```
CREATE INDEX payments_application_tour_ids_gin_idx ON payments
USING gin (f_extract_tour_ids(application));
```

Match the expression and use an indexable array operator in your queries to be applicable, like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   payment
WHERE  f_extract_tour_ids(application) @> '{d61802ff-3eec-4a72-97ca-832f51b96bf0}'::uuid[];
```

As you can see, you can search for any number of UUIDs at once with this query.

---

***Or***, if you can't (or won't) create the operator class, you can work with the `text` representation of the UUID values - which is considerably bigger and hence more expensive.

Adapt `f_extract_tour_ids(jsonb)` like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_extract_tour_ids(jsonb)
  RETURNS text[] AS
$func$
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT (jsonb_array_elements($1) #>> '{tour_id, id}'))
$func$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

And the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   payment
WHERE  f_extract_tour_ids(application) @> '{d61802ff-3eec-4a72-97ca-832f51b96bf0}'::text[];
```

Be sure to match the UUID format exactly.

Related:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array)
- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)
- [Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89429/would-index-lookup-be-noticeably-faster-with-char-vs-varchar-when-all-values-are/89433#89433)

Comment: hi Erwin, the moment to create the index has arrived, but i think i'd like to separate the index, by example, i want to look for the id inside tour {}, how do it ?

Comment: @stackdave: Not sure I understand. I suggest you post a new *question* with details needed to clarify. You can always link to this one for context.

Comment: @stackdave: Note the updates concerning `uuid[]`.