# Index by subkey inside subkey inside array in jsonb

Tags: postgresql, index, index-tuning, json

I have a `jsonb` field `registration` that contains an array of objects. I need to create two separates indexes to look for `id`, by example:

```
d61802ff-3eec-4a72-97ca-832f51b96bf0 = [ .tour_id.id ]
f492b26d-d260-4bcb-8e96-6532fdf38665 = [ .customer_id.id ]
```

Example data (I have more keys and arrays, but it's a resume)

```
[
   {
    "tour_id":
      {
        "id":"d61802ff-3eec-4a72-97ca-832f51b96bf0",
        "name":"Paris  2018"
      },
    "customer_id":
      {
        "id":"f492b26d-d260-4bcb-8e96-6532fdf38665",
        "name":"OBAMA John"
      }
   },
   {
    "tour_id":
      {
        "id":"a52d38d4-9bfb-4ffa-1122-e536f04b0c60",
        "name":"London  2018"
      },
    "customer_id":
      {
        "id":"f492b26d-d260-4bcb-8e96-6532fdf38665",
        "name":"OBAMA John"
      }
   }
]
```

How to index by `[array].customer_id.id`?
Or is there a method to index by *subkey.subkey*? Or deeper nested subkey?

I'm using Postgres 9.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*First off, I would consider a normalized DB design instead of the convoluted `jsonb` column, which makes indexing and complex queries harder.*

> How to index by `[array].customer_id.id`?

See my answer to your previous question:

- [Index by subkey in jsonb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193377/index-by-subkey-in-jsonb-postgres-9-6/193378#193378)

You could have ***two*** GIN indexes like instructed there, one on `tour_id`, another one on `customer_id`, or a single multicolumn index, and then query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE  f_extract_tour_ids(registration)     @> '{d61802ff-3eec-4a72-97ca-832f51b96bf0}'::uuid[]
AND    f_extract_customer_ids(registration) @> '{f492b26d-d260-4bcb-8e96-6532fdf38665}'::uuid[];
```

**Note**, this returns rows with `tour_id` and `customer_id` matching in *any* top-level object of the array, not necessarily in the same. If you want to find rows where `tour_id` and `customer_id` match in the *same* object, you have to do more ...

#### `jsonb_path_ops` index

**However**, with a growing number of different queries (requiring multiple special indexes), a single generic (much bigger) [**`jsonb_path_ops`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/gin-builtin-opclasses.html) index on the whole column becomes more competitive. Or even one with the default operator class operator class [`jsonb_ops`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/gin-builtin-opclasses.html) - which is bigger, yet.

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON tbl USING GIN (registration jsonb_path_ops);
```

Queries to go with it:

For rows with `tour_id` and `customer_id` matching in the *same* top-level object:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE  registration @> '[{"tour_id": {"id": "d61802ff-3eec-4a72-97ca-832f51b96bf0"}
                        , "customer_id": {"id": "f492b26d-d260-4bcb-8e96-6532fdf38665"}}]';
```

For rows with `tour_id` and `customer_id` matching in *any* top-level object, not necessarily the same:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE  registration @> '[{"tour_id": {"id": "d61802ff-3eec-4a72-97ca-832f51b96bf0"}}
                       , {"customer_id":{"id":"f492b26d-d260-4bcb-8e96-6532fdf38665"}}]';
```

This solution is slower because of the much bigger index carrying all the other noise in your `jsonb` column. But it is much more versatile and simpler.
If the first solutions make your head ache, use this one.

Comment: 'first solutions makes your head ache, use this one.', this is better CREATE INDEX foo ON tbl USING GIN (registration jsonb_path_ops) ? yes sometimes i will need to look for just record widh a tour_id; sometimes with customer_id, really i don't want to come back to traditional  normalize database after using it long years, JSONB is modern and it's a fresh air that match very well with the front react-app redux-form and array fields. My idea is sync postgresql with couchdb, and then with pouchdb on the browser.

Comment: @stackdave: There is nothing wrong with JSON in the DB per se. If you can work with JSON documents in your app directly, that's a major benefit. There are just many use cases that perform much better with a normalized design. The right tool for the job ...