# How to use default value of data type as column default?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, datatypes, ddl

How can I specify the default value for a column in the DDL? I was pretty sure that the following method worked a while ago:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  col_1 CHAR(12) NOT NULL,
  col_2 INTEGER  NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT,
  col_3 CHAR(12) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT
);
```

I would just like to define that the DB should use the default value for the column data type (like in my example above), without specifying which value exactly.

Comment: Are you sure it was for PostgreSQL? I've seen `WITH DEFAULT` been used in Db2, but it is not standard AFAIK.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The *default* default value for any new table column is the default value of the data type.

And the *default* default value for data types is `NULL` - which is the case for *all* basic data types in Postgres. But any valid value is allowed for custom types or domains.

[The manual on `CREATE TYPE`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html)

> A default value can be specified, in case a user wants columns of the
> data type to default to something other than the null value. Specify
> the default with the `DEFAULT` key word. (Such a default can be
> overridden by an explicit `DEFAULT` clause attached to a particular column.)

[The manual on `CREATE DOMAIN`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdomain.html)

> The default expression will be used in any insert operation that does
> not specify a value for the column. If a default value is defined for
> a particular column, it overrides any default associated with the
> domain. In turn, the domain default overrides any default value
> associated with the underlying data type.

You only use the `DEFAULT` clause for columns in [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) to specify a *different* default. Else, you **do nothing**. <strike>`WITH DEFAULT`</strike> like you display in the question is not valid in Postgres

To **reset** a column default to the *default* default of the data type (typically `NULL`), *drop* the specified default value of the column.

[The manual on `ALTER TABLE`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)

> ```
> ALTER [ COLUMN ] column_name DROP DEFAULT
> ```

[`NOT NULL` constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#id-1.5.4.5.6) are related but completely independent. A column defined `NOT NULL` and with no custom `DEFAULT` (and no not-null default for the type) requires you to provide a not-null value for every `INSERT`.

---

Aside: don't use the data type `char(12)`. See:

- [Any downsides of using data type “text” for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334221/939860)
- [Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89429/would-index-lookup-be-noticeably-faster-with-char-vs-varchar-when-all-values-are/89433#89433)

Answer (score 7):

You should specify what is the default. If I remember correctly the DEFAULT should be before NOT NULL:

```
CREATE TABLE test
( col_1 CHAR(12) NOT NULL,
  col_2 INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  col_3 CHAR(12) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: `DEFAULT` can be after the `NOT NULL` constraint.

Comment: @MayRestinPeace, yes it can in all DBMS that I know of, but I remembered vaguely that the SQL standard says that DEFAULT should be first. That's why I mentioned it

Comment: I don't have the time to look up the ref now, but you can try: `CREATE TABLE T ( x int default 3 not null  );` vs `CREATE TABLE T ( x int not null default 3 );` at https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/