# Index performance for CHAR vs VARCHAR (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, performance, varchar

In this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517579/strings-as-primary-keys-in-sql-database) a single remark caught my eye:

> Also keep in mind that there's often a very big difference between a
>   CHAR and a VARCHAR when doing index comparisons

Does this apply / still apply for Postgres?

I found pages on Oracle claiming that `CHAR` is more or less an alias for `VARCHAR` and so index performance is the same, but I found nothing definitive on Postgres.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`CHAR` and `VARCHAR` are implemented exactly the same in Postgres (and Oracle). There is no difference in speed when using those data types.

However, there is one difference that *can* make a difference in performance: a `char` column is always padded to the defined length. So if you define a column as `char(100)` and one as `varchar(100)` but only store 10 characters in each, the `char(100)` column uses 100 characters for each value (the 10 characters you stored, plus 90 spaces), whereas the `varchar` column only stores 10 characters.

Comparing 100 character with 100 characters is going to be slower than comparing 10 characters with 10 characters - although I doubt you can actually measure this difference in a SQL query.

If you declare both with the length of 10 characters and always store **exactly** 10 characters in them, then there is absolutely no difference whatsoever (this is true for Oracle and Postgres)

So the only difference is the padding that is done for the `char` data type.

---

> Also keep in mind that there's often a very big difference between a CHAR and a VARCHAR when doing index comparisons

The above quote is **only** true if (and only if) the `char` column is defined too wide (i.e. you are wasting space due to padding). If the length of the `char` column is always used completely (so no padding occurs), then the above quote is wrong (at least for Postgres and Oracle)

---

From my point of view, the `char` data type does not really have any real-word use. Just use `varchar` (or `text` in Postgres) and forget that `char` exists.

Comment: *Comparing 100 character with 100 characters is going to be slower than comparing 10 characters with 10 characters - although I doubt you can actually measure this difference in a SQL query.* – Depending on what the query does in addition to sorting, the difference can be huge. That’s why Postgres 9.5 has a new “abbreviated keys” feature: http://pgeoghegan.blogspot.de/2015/01/abbreviated-keys-exploiting-locality-to.html

Answer (score 9):

I agree with everything [said](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/126047) by a_horse_with_no_name, and I generally agree with Erwin's comment advice:

> No, char is inferior (and outdated). text and varchar perform (almost) the same.

## Metadata

With one minor exception, the **only** time I use `char()` is when I want the meta-data to say this **MUST** have have x-characters. Though I know that `char()` only complains if the input is over the limit, I'll frequently protect against underruns in a `CHECK` constraint. For example,

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  x char(10) CHECK ( length(x) = 10 )
);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (repeat('x', 9));
```

I do this for a few reasons,

1. `char(x)` is sometimes inferred with schema-loaders as being a fixed-width column. This may make a difference in a language that is optimized for fixed-width strings.
2. It establishes a convention that makes sense and is easily enforced. I can write a schema-loader in a language to generate code from this convention.

Need an example of where I may do this,

1. Two-letter state abbreviations, though because this list can be enumerated, I'll typically do it with an `ENUM`.
2. [Vehicle Identification Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_identification_number)
3. Model Numbers (of fixed size)

### On errors

Notice some people may be uncomfortable with the incongruity of error messages on both sides of the limit, but it doesn't bother me

```
test=# INSERT INTO foo VALUES (repeat('x', 9));
ERROR:  new row for relation "foo" violates check constraint "foo_x_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (xxxxxxxxx ).
test=# INSERT INTO foo VALUES (repeat('x', 11));
ERROR:  value too long for type character(10)
```

## Contrast with `varchar`

Moreover, I think the above suggestion fits really well with a convention of ***almost* always use `text`**. You ask about `varchar(n)` too. **I never use that**. At least, I can't remember the last time I used `varchar(n)`.

- If a spec has a static-width field that I trust, I use `char(n)`,
- Otherwise, I use `text` which is effectively `varchar` (no limit)

If I found a spec that had variable-length text-keys that were meaningful and that I trusted to have a constant max-length, I would use `varchar(n)` too. However, I can't think of anything that fits that criteria.

## Additional notes

- [`char` here is not to be confused with `"char"`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166155/how-exactly-does-the-one-byte-char-type-work-in-postgresql) which is a one-byte type and has solid performance and space-saving benefits.

Related Q & A:

- [Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89433/3684)
- [What is the overhead for varchar(n)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/125526/3684)

Comment: And then there is [Don't use char(n) even for fixed-length identifiers](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29_even_for_fixed-length_identifiers)

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql

```
sales_reporting_db=# create table x (y char(2));
CREATE TABLE
sales_reporting_db=# insert into x values ('Y');
INSERT 0 1
sales_reporting_db=# select '*' || y || '*' from x;
 ?column? 
----------
 *Y*
```

Oracle

```
SQL> create table x ( y char(2));

Table created.

SQL> insert into x values ('Y');

1 row created.

SQL> select '*' || y || '*' from x;

'*'|
----
*Y *
```

Postgresql did not pad with spaces.

Comment: That's just an optical illusion in Postgres.  Try `SELECT pg_column_size(y) FROM x;`

Answer (score -1):

I found this most useful, and a fast 3 line explanation:

> From [CHAR(n) Vs VARCHAR(N) Vs Text In Postgres](http://www.itsupportforum.net/topic/charn-vs-varcharn-vs-text-in-postgres/)
>
> - If you want to store some text with an unknown length, use the `TEXT` data type.
> - If you want to store some text with an unknown length, but you know the maximum length, use `VARCHAR(n)`.
> - If you want to store some text with a known exact length, use `CHAR(N)`.

Comment: I was wondering why this got voted down. I think it's because check constraints and the like are considered a better way of enforcing string length because there is no penalty for changing them later. Due to that, most people suggest always using TEXT type.