# In PostgreSQL, what is the behavior of the bit(n) -> "char" cast?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, cast

Using PostgreSQL if I cast

```
65::bit(8)::"char"
```

I get `0`, if I however cast

```
65::bit(8)::int::"char"
```

I get `A` as I would expect.

```
SELECT
  v,
  v::bit(8)::"char" AS noint,
  v::bit(8)::int::"char" AS "viaInt"
FROM (VALUES (65)) AS t(v);
 v  | noint | viaInt 
----+-------+--------
 65 | 0     | A
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the cast directly to `"char"` without going through `int` first is taking the first character from the stringification of the bitfield.

```
SELECT 65::bit(8);
   bit    
----------
 01000001
(1 row)

SELECT '01000001'::"char", '0'::"char";
 char | char 
------+------
 0    | 0
(1 row)
```

If that was greater than 128, you'd have a one in that position,

```
SELECT 128::bit(8);
   bit    
----------
 10000000
(1 row)
```

Casting that to `"char"` would give you a `1` rather than a `0`,

```
SELECT 128::bit(8)::"char";
 char 
------
 1
(1 row)
```

**Keep in mind, "char" is signed, so the range is `[-128,127]`.** For this reason you can't actually go from `bit(8)` to `"char`" without first shifting those bits. For example

```
SELECT 128::bit(8)::int::"char";
ERROR:  "char" out of range
```

See also

- [How exactly does the one-byte “char” type work in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/166155/2639)