# optimizing or estimating postgresql table size on disk

Tags: postgresql, disk-space

This question is in the context of the [helpcovid](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid) GPLv3+ project (work in progress in March 2020). With PostgreSQL 11 on Debian/Buster/x86-64. See the [file `hcv_database.cc`](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/blob/master/hcv_database.cc) there.

I have a table of web users:

```
---- TABLE tb_user
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tb_user (
  user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,  -- unique user_id
  user_firstname VARCHAR(31) NOT NULL,  -- first name, in capitals, UTF8
  user_familyname VARCHAR(62) NOT NULL, -- family name, in capitals, UTF8
  user_email VARCHAR(71) NOT NULL,      -- email, in lowercase, UTF8
  user_gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,         -- 'F' | 'M' | '?'
  user_crtime DATE NOT NULL             -- user entry creation time
); --- end TABLE tb_user
```

Imagine I have a million rows in that table, and 99% of users have a `user_firstname` of less than 16 bytes, and 99% of users have a `user_family` of less than 32 bytes.

Assume that this table is only filled by [`INSERT` SQL statements](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-insert/).

What would be the estimated disk space consumption of the PostgreSQL files (under `/var/lib/postgreql`) containing that database. As measured by `du -h`

For simplicity, assume that this table is the only one in the database.

To ask the question otherwise, the `VARCHAR(31)` size is used for *every* row on disk, or not?

In other words, how practically important is the width of columns in tables, w.r.t to disk space?

Related question: [How does Postgres store many varchars on disk?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/258898)

Comment: The _declared_ width of the column is completely irrelevant. It only matters what values you _store_ in the columns.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to run a little benchmark:

```
INSERT INTO tb_user
   (user_firstname, user_familyname, user_email, user_gender, user_crtime)
SELECT substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 15),
       substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 15),
       md5(random()::text),
       'F',
       current_date
FROM generate_series(1, 1000000);

SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('tb_user'));

 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 126 MB
(1 row)
```

A `text` or `varchar` that is short enough (which the ones in the table certainly are) will consume one byte more than the number of bytes in the string.

There is some overhead caused by block and tuples headers and other metadata, as well as by fragmentation (some empty space will remain in each 8kB block). And then the index that supports the primary key is also sizeable:

```
\di+ tb_user_pkey 
                            List of relations
 Schema  |     Name     | Type  |  Owner  |  Table  | Size  | Description 
---------+--------------+-------+---------+---------+-------+-------------
 laurenz | tb_user_pkey | index | laurenz | tb_user | 21 MB | 
(1 row)
```

Some additional hints:

- You can save a little space by having `user_crtime` in the second position. Otherwise, you might lose up to three bytes to padding.
- Use `bigint` for the primary key so that you can never run out of values. Trying to save on these 4 bytes is usually not a good idea.