# Sensible max_length for Postgres db charfields

Tags: postgresql, varchar, django

I am using Django with a Postgres backend.

In the Django models, I have to set the max_length attribute on the Charfields, then the Django ORM deals with the database in the backend. In a lot of cases, those are rather small fields (e.g. say names, or city names etc.) that I don't expect would be very long.
That application deals with existing data that isn't particularly cleaned. So I don't want to set something like

```
name = models.Charfield(max_length=50, ...)
```

Just to realize that someone triple wrote his name in that field and that the field is 75 characters long. On the other hand, I don't want to set huge values and needlessly increase database size just to save me a little bit of trouble.

My current thinking is that Postgres probably reserves some minimal amount of space (e.g. likely that max_length=10 and max_length=15 both take the same storage), so I would set the max_length to that minimal size (or low multiple thereof).

What do you recommend and why?

Comment: `VARCHAR` values only occupy as much space as the actual strings they contain (plus length, typically two bytes). So, if Django maps `Charfield` to `VARCHAR`, no space is wasted. Also, [this](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: Okay, but I still have the same question about similar test fields in django which may or not map to Varchad( perhaps to Text, or Char....).

Comment: Interesting reading btw - but yeah, part of my thinking is that I don't want to be too restrictive. But at the same time not want to waste storage either.

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions: you are not wasting storage if you use `varchar` or `text` - Postgres only stores as many characters as you put into the columns. You should see the length limit as a _business_ constraint, rather than a technical restriction.

Comment: Only use a length restriction to restrict the maximum number of characters - if you *need* that. It has no bearing whatsoever on storage size. If there is no need to restrict maximum length, just use `text`. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/125499/3684, https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21496/3684, https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89433/3684

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no length limit imposed by the application logic, use `text` rather than `varchar`. This is better than imposing an arbitrary length limit.

`text` and `varchar` are the same under the hood in PostgreSQL, and a string will only occupy as much space as it actually needs. You won't lose performance.

Comment: From this & the comments, I realized that I hadn't really given much thoughts about the difference between varchar vs text types (from a db perspective). Partly because the source application I'm migrating from only uses a single type. So yes, I think you are right, I need to ask myself the question on a specific field, I probably just really want to be using a text, not varchar. Thanks for the background on the inner workings - that's what I was fuzzy about, and couldn't find that in the docs.