# Do datatypes of columns affect query performance?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, query-performance, optimization

Let's suppose I have this table:

```
Table "public.orders"
         Column      |     Type      | Collation | Nullable | Default 
    -----------------+---------------+-----------+----------+---------
     o_orderkey      | integer       |           | not null | 
     o_custkey       | integer       |           |          | 
     o_orderstatus   | character(1)  |           |          | 
     o_totalprice    | numeric(12,2) |           |          | 
     o_orderdate     | date          |           |          | 
     o_orderpriority | character(15) |           |          | 
     o_clerk         | character(15) |           |          | 
     o_shippriority  | integer       |           |          | 
     o_comment       | character(79) |           |          |
```

If I have queries involving `o_orderstatus`, `o_orderpriority`, `o_clerk` or `o_comment` columns, can I change `char(n)` datatype to `text` in order to improve them?

Comment: [This](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/query-parameter-data-types-performance/) does not answer the question, but is relevant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes**. And probably **a lot**.

You never *gain* performance using `character(n)`(alias `char(n)`). You don't gain anything at all because that type is outdated, mostly useless, and [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29). Related:

- [Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89429/would-index-lookup-be-noticeably-faster-with-char-vs-varchar-when-all-values-are/89433#89433)

But you saw that bit in the quote from [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) where it says:

> apart from increased storage space when using the blank-padded type

`char(n)` is the blank-padded type. And column names like `comment` indicate mostly blank-padded waste. `text` or `varchar` remove the bloat and everything around your table becomes **substantially** faster, as your avg. row size probably shrinks to less than half. More tuples per data page means fewer pages to read and process per query, and that is the most important factor for performance there is.

While being at it, order columns favorably to make it more efficient, yet:

```
   Column      |     Type      | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------------+---------------+-----------+----------+---------
 orderkey      | integer       |           | not null | 
 custkey       | integer       |           |          | 
 orderdate     | date          |           |          | 
 shippriority  | integer       |           |          | 
 totalprice    | numeric(12,2) |           |          | 
 orderstatus   | varchar(1)    |           |          | 
 orderpriority | varchar(15)   |           |          | 
 clerk         | varchar(15)   |           |          | 
 comment       | varchar(79)   |           |          |
```

Why?

- [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/939860)

I kept the length restrictions with `varchar(n)`, but if those are just arbitrary, use `text` instead. A tiny bit faster, yet. (And less corner-case hassle.) See:

- [Should I add an arbitrary length limit to VARCHAR columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20974/should-i-add-an-arbitrary-length-limit-to-varchar-columns/21496#21496)

Comment: The TEXT column size is much larger than other types like integer.... wouldn't this slow down reads (fewer records returned in each disk io)?

Comment: @wolf2600: You seem to be confusing Postgres with some other RDBMS, where the data type "text" has different characteristics. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/125526/3684 (Of course, use `integer` where appropriate!)

Comment: Yeah, I'd been working with an older archaic DW system where we'd see problems when teams would create tables with dozens of unnecessarily large varchar() columns ("just in case!") when trying to figure out query performance issues.  But apparently Postgres TEXT manages that fine.