# How can I get a range of values from sparse data

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table (simplified):

```
create table tunnels
(
    interval          varchar          not null,
    ts_start          timestamp        not null,
    ts_end            timestamp,
    price_top         double precision not null,
    price_bottom      double precision not null,
)
```

Those represent segments, delimited by ts_start, ts_end and a range price_top, price_bottom.

The data is sparse and rows are created only when something changes.
There are several timeframes running at the same time, represented by 'interval'

I would like to make a query where I request a time range and get an array where I get the values for each interval existing.

Some sample data is here: https://pastebin.com/P1mugdtk

What I'm looking for is some array with interpolated values by the minute by interval (they're represented as strings: M1, M5, etc. right now), with rows like:

```
[ ts: xxx, m1_price_top: xx, m1_price_bottom: xx, m5: price_top: xx, m5: price_bottom: xx, ...]
[ ts: xxx, m1_price_top: xx, m1_price_bottom: xx, m5: price_top: xx, m5: price_bottom: xx, ...]
```

to add a bit more complexity, within a time range, we need the previous record, for each interval, to know where to start and ts_end can be null if there is no data that closes that segment (it's always the last record).

how can I achieve that in postgres?

Comment: Your pastebin data is not runnable as a script - please put in the necessary brackets and quotes!

Comment: @Vérace I've made an sql insert file: https://pastebin.com/weLFKzTn

Comment: `where I get the values for each interval existing.` - I presume you mean "interval overlapping"?

Comment: @Vérace, sorry it wasn't clear: the intervals are various strings (M5, M15, etc) and I'm looking for an array of arrays where for each interval, there is an array that's interpolated by the minute.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by `interpolated by the minute` - please take a small subset from the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/JL--JlYw) and show me what you mean - before and after...

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me to be an excellent use case for PostgreSQL's range data type(s)!

I've created your table with a few changes as follows (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/9jywcRMG?hide=131072)):

```
CREATE TABLE tunnels
(
  t_interval   TEXT         NOT NULL,  -- TEXT is better virtually **always**
  ts_start     TIMESTAMPTZ  NOT NULL,  -- With timezone better if possible!
  ts_end       TIMESTAMPTZ,
  price_top    REAL         NOT NULL,  -- REAL should be good enough - adjust as you
  price_bottom REAL         NOT NULL,   -- see fit!

  CONSTRAINT ts_lt_te    CHECK (ts_start < ts_end),
  CONSTRAINT ti_ts_te_uq UNIQUE (t_interval, ts_start, ts_end)
);
```

A few  points to note:

- the `TEXT` type is almost **always** preferable to `VARCHAR` (first field) - see [`here`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21496/34007), [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334221/470530) and [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23988687/470530) - (these posters are PostgreSQL experts!) - I also changed its name because `INTERVAL` is a PostgreSQL keyword. [`SQL keywords`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words) should **never** be used as field or table names, it makes debugging difficult and makes your app non-portable
- again, the `TIMESTAMPTZ` is virtually always preferable to `TIMESTAMP` - see [`here`](https://justatheory.com/2012/04/postgres-use-timestamptz/), [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922155/postgresql-jdbc-and-timestamp-vs-timestamptz) and [`here`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/time-data-types-postgresql/)
- I've used `REAL` instead of `DOUBLE PRECISION` - this just depends on how much precision you actually need - the former takes up 4 bytes, the latter 8. See [`here`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) for details. Basically, you should only use as much precision as you require, but I'm not aware of your requirements in this area, so this is just a suggestion - *à vous le choix*!
- I've added a couple of constraints which would help to weed out bad data - there's no bad data in your sample (however, see below)
- I've hidden the table insert statement snippet in the fiddle (pain to scroll through all the time - it's just below the table definition)

So, now we come to PostgreSQL's [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) (Functions and Opertors ([`manual`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html)), also see [`here`](https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/04/postgresql-data-types-ranges/) and [`here`](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/range-types-recursion-how-to-search-availability-with-postgresql) for a couple of nice use cases). PostgreSQL is the only mainstream RDBMS which has these out of the box.

We will use the `TSTZRANGE` (range of times with `TIMESTAMPTZ`) type as follows:

```
SELECT 
  t_interval AS t_int, 
  TSTZRANGE(ts_start, ts_end) AS range,
  price_bottom AS pb, price_top AS pt,
  ts_start AS ts, ts_end AS te
FROM 
  tunnels
WHERE ts_start >= '2023-10-02' AND ts_end < '2023-10-04'
  AND 
  TSTZRANGE(ts_start, ts_end) 
  @> 
  '2023-10-03 19:20:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ  
ORDER BY 
  t_interval, ts_start
LIMIT 20;
```

Result:

```
t_int  range                                                pb    pt                 ts                   te
   H1  ["2023-10-03 18:00:00+00","2023-10-03 21:00:00+00")  27212.3     27479.5     2023-10-03 18:00:00+00  2023-10-03 21:00:00+00
   H2  ["2023-10-03 06:00:00+00","2023-10-03 22:00:00+00")  27255   27633.3     2023-10-03 06:00:00+00  2023-10-03 22:00:00+00
  M15  ["2023-10-03 19:15:00+00","2023-10-03 19:30:00+00")  27230   27479.5     2023-10-03 19:15:00+00  2023-10-03 19:30:00+00
  M30  ["2023-10-03 18:00:00+00","2023-10-03 20:30:00+00")  27212.3     27479.5     2023-10-03 18:00:00+00  2023-10-03 20:30:00+00
   M5  ["2023-10-03 19:05:00+00","2023-10-03 19:25:00+00")  27230   27479.5     2023-10-03 19:05:00+00  2023-10-03 19:25:00+00
```

(I've put another couple of examples at the bottom of the fiddle.)

- Check out the `@>` notation - it means "Containment" - you can check out the other operators from the manual.
- Note the [`bounds`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INCLUSIVITY) of the range - starts with `[` and ends with `)` - the `[` is inclusive whereas the `)` is exclusive. This is **very** important!

> In the text form of a range, an inclusive lower bound is represented
> by “[” while an exclusive lower bound is represented by “(”. Likewise,
> an inclusive upper bound is represented by “]”, while an exclusive
> upper bound is represented by “)”. (See Section 8.17.5 for more
> details).

If you run `SELECT * FROM tunnels ORDER BY t_interval, ts_start LIMIT 2;` with your sample data, the result is:

```
t_interval  ts_start                ts_end              price_top   price_bottom
        D1  2023-10-03 00:00:00+00  2023-10-04 00:00:00+00  28613   25965
        D1  2023-10-04 00:00:00+00  2023-10-09 00:00:00+00  28613   27123
```

Now, you can see where `ts_end` of the first record matches the `ts_start` of the second - conceivably you could have two different prices at the same point in time - this is probably **not** a good idea. I ran a  query (see fiddle) and your data doesn't appear to suffer from this, but it **could**.

Now, notice the range colums - they start with `[` and end with `)` - so no overlaps! For any instant, there can only be one value of `price_bottom`, `price_top` - see my question in the fiddle as to why values match in succeeding records.

Now, we come to the *pièce de résistance* of PostgreSQL's capabilities in this area! First we'll do an `INSERT` as follows:

```
--
--  Works, but overlaps with (see above)
--  D1  2023-10-03  2023-10-04  2   2   2023-10-04  27123   28613
--

INSERT INTO tunnels VALUES ('D1', '2023-10-03 01:00:00+00', '2023-10-04 05:00:00+00', 2, 2);
```

We don't want overlaps to be possible!

So, we do the following: `CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;`. From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html), we have:

> btree_gist provides GiST index operator classes that implement B-tree
> equivalent behavior for the data types int2, int4, int8, float4,
> float8, numeric, timestamp with time zone, timestamp without time
> zone, time with time zone, time without time zone, date, interval,
> oid, money, char, varchar, text, bytea, bit, varbit, macaddr,
> macaddr8, inet, cidr, uuid, bool and all enum types.

Note `"text"` (and `"varchar"`) - without the extension, these types won't work with [`GiST indexes`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gist-intro.html) - not for btree like indexes anyway - try running the fiddle without the extension.

There is a whole [ecosystem](https://gist.github.com/joelonsql/e5aa27f8cc9bd22b8999b7de8aee9d47) of PostgreSQL extensions (another feature unique to PostgreSQL), [`here`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib.html) are the "contrib" modules that are available - and this is only scratching the surface - see [here](https://airbyte.com/data-engineering-resources/postgresql-extensions), [here](https://www.timescale.com/blog/top-5-postgresql-extensions/) & [here](https://www.bytebase.com/blog/top-postgres-extension/#pgvector). Contrib modules are not part of the core, but held in high esteem and distributed with the core.

After `DELETE`-ing the offending record, we create an index:

```
CREATE INDEX ti_ts_te_range_ix 
ON tunnels
USING GIST (t_interval, TSTZRANGE(ts_start, ts_end));
```

and we alter our table and establish a non-overlapping constraint as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE tunnels ADD CONSTRAINT ts_te_no_overlap_ct
EXCLUDE USING GIST (t_interval WITH =, TSTZRANGE(ts_start, ts_end) WITH &&);
```

and then we retry our `INSERT` - Result:

```
ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "ts_te_no_overlap_ct"
DETAIL:  Key (t_interval, tstzrange(ts_start, ts_end))=(D1, ["2023-10-03 01:00:00+00","2023-10-04 05:00:00+00")) 
conflicts with existing key (t_interval, tstzrange(ts_start, ts_end))=(D1, ["2023-10-03 00:00:00+00","2023-10-04 00:00:00+00")).
```

So, I hope this answers your question or at least goes some way towards doing so. You say you want an `array of arrays` - I'm not sure if that's a good idea - manipulating long strings is **not** SQL's forté - it's far better at "slicing and dicing" data "atoms" - i.e. no .csv fields for example - see [Codd's rules](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules):

> Rule 2: The guaranteed access rule:
>
> Each and every datum (atomic value) in a relational data base is
> guaranteed to be logically accessible by resorting to a combination of
> table name, primary key value and column name.

Two final points:

- 1. PostgreSQL recently introduced the multirange type - that might be of interest to you if you wish to have long strings (a processing nightmare!) - a couple of articles - code [before](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/range-types-recursion-how-to-search-availability-with-postgresql) multirange and code [after](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/better-range-types-in-postgres-14-turning-100-lines-of-sql-into-3#a-real-world-example-availability)!
- 2. If you like, another thing you could do is to use a `GENERATED` column - it can make your SQL more elegant at the price of a bit of disk space - you can do this as follows (see small sample fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/zqND63VG)):

  `ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN z TSTZRANGE  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TSTZRANGE(x, y)) STORED;`

If the answer above doesn't satisfy you, well maybe the multirange approach can be adapted to your requirements - ping me on the comments! Interesting question - I learnt a lot (+1)!